# Option Strict On and .NET for VB6 programmers

Tags: .net, vb.net, late-binding

I'm preparing a class on Visual Basic 2005 targeting Visual Basic 6 programmers migrating to the .NET platform.
I would like a word of advice about whether to recommend them to always enable **Option Strict** or not.
I've worked exclusively with C-style programming languages, mostly Java and C#, so for me **explicit casting** is something I always expect I have to do, since it's never been an option.
However I recognize the value of working with a language that has built-in support for **late-binding**, because not having to be excessively explicit about types in the code indeed saves time. This is further proved by the popular diffusion of **dynamic typed languages**, even on the .NET platform with the Dynamic Language Runtime.

With this in mind, should someone who is approaching .NET for the first time using VB.NET and with a VB6 background be encouraged to get into the mindset of **having to work with compile-time type checking** because that's the "best practice" in the CLR? Or is it "OK" to continue enjoying the benefits of late-binding?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes!  Option Strict is definitely a best practice with .Net.  Emphasize that .Net is at it's core a strongly typed platform, and will be until the DLR is more completely supported.  With few exceptions, every `Dim` and `Function` should have an explicit type declared to go with it.  Things like LINQ or Boo and JScript are the exceptions that prove the rule.

Here are some other things to point out. I'm sure you're well aware of all this, but I've had to work with and maintain a lot of VB.Net code written by former VB6ers, and so this is something of a sore spot for me:

- Don't use the old string functions: `LEN()`, `REPLACE()`, `TRIM()`, etc
- Hungarian warts are no longer recommended.  `oMyObject` and `sMyString` are not kosher.  Show them the reference in [Microsoft's Design Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx) if they don't believe you.
- Make sure they learn about the new `AndAlso`/`OrElse` logical operators
- PARAMETERIZED QUERIES and modern ADO.Net.  Can't emphasize that enough.  They should never need to call `CreateObject()` again.
- Scope works differently (and is more important) in .Net than it was in VB6.  VB.Net still has modules, but they're now more analogous to a static class.  It's important to understand how developing in a real object oriented environment be different, as opposed to the partial OOP support provided by VB6.  There's no good reason anymore to allow methods to run to ungodly lengths.
- Make sure they get an introduction to Generics and Interfaces (including `IEnumeralbe(Of T)`), and learn why they should never use an `ArrayList` again.

I could keep going, but I'll just point you to the [Hidden Features of VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102084/hidden-features-of-vbnet) Question to close out this rant.

Comment: “Every Dim and Function should have an explicit type declared to go with it.” - No! `Option Infer On` to the rescue (only for `Dim`s though).

Comment: Good point: I'm still stuck in .Net 2.0. You are allowed to break this rule for things like LINQ expressions in later versions.

Comment: Also, your first point's justification is wrong: No VB6 runtime is called! The calls may be redundant and bad style (inconsistent) but certainly not evil. Some even have tangible advantages (take `MsgBox` for example).

Comment: I went looking trying to find where I had read about MS.VB.dll calling out to the old runtime and I coudln't find it, so I just removed the reference completely.

Comment: Good points! Yes, my biggest challenge with this class is indeed to teach them the concepts of Object-Oriented programming first and foremost. The fact that they get to keep the same language syntax they are used to is a minor luxury.

Comment: Instead of telling them not to use the compatibility functions, tell them to remove the global import of Microsoft.VisualBasic. They can still use the old functions by typing out the full namespace, but that's time consuming and ugly. A good way to make it costly to use the old stuff.

Comment: Didn't really answer the question in my opinion. Without option strict the compiler will do the conversions for you, so why bother adding them explicitly and have to add about 5% extra code everywhere? It is something that is necessary for C-type languages, but for VB.net, I really do not see the advantage. Option explicit should be enough to address you point about type declarations.

Answer (score 18):

Time spent developing with Option Strict enable will save you tremendous amount of debugging time later on.

Comment: I agree. But couldn't that risk be mitigated by make good use of Unit Testing, like for dynamic languages?

Comment: Possibly, but these people are migrating from VB6 - do you really want to throw unit testing at the same time?

Answer (score 8):

`Option Strict` obviously can't replace good unit testing – but neither the other way round. While unit testing *can* detect the same errors as `Option Strict`, this implies that there's no error in the unit tests, that unit testing is done often and early, etc ….

Writing good unit tests isn't always trivial and takes time. However, the compiler already implements some of the tests – in the form of type checking. At the very least, this saves time. More likely, this saves *a lot of* time and money (at least occasionally) because your tests were erroneous / didn't cover all cases / forgot to account for changes in the code.

To sum it up, there's no guarantee that your unit tests are correct. On the other hand, there's a strong guarantee that the type checking performed by the compiler is correct or at least that its glitches (unchecked array covariance, bugs with circular references …) are well-known and well-documented.

Another sum-up: **Yes, `Option Strict On` is definitely best practice.** In fact, I've worked for years in online communities like this one. Whenever someone needed help on code that obviously didn't have `Option Strict` enabled, we'd politely point this out and refuse to give any further help until this was fixed. It saves so much time. Often, the problem was gone after this. This is somewhat analogous to using correct HTML when asking help in a HTML support forum: invalid HTML might work, but then again, it might not and be the cause of the problems. Therefore, many professionals refuse to help.

Comment: Great answer. The only thing I would add is to set warnings to be treated as errors at compile time. Also - when developing web sites, I set my compatibility to the most strict level (currently doctype XHTML 1.1) for the same reason.

Comment: Agreed. The extra verbosity in code due to explicit casting of variables does not compare to the great amount of time saved by letting the compiler do its job. Thanks for a great answer!

Answer (score 5):

YES!!!!

In my opinion, both as a developer, and as a college instructor YES.

It is best to get into the good habits from the start, it makes the whole process much easier, and Option Strict is one of those items that in my opinion is a NEEDED element.

*added*

There are literally tons of reasons that could be listed as to why, but the key is that it is a best practice, and when teaching a new language, it is key to teach those best practices from the start.

Answer (score 4):

Remember there are two levels here.

Option Explicit
Option Strict

The main difference between the two is that Option Strict disable VB's automatic conversion of different data types. You have to explicitly use CType or another data conversion function to assign a variable to another type.

I been using VB since 1.0 and while I can see the point of this I think that Strict is over zealous paritcularily when dealing with Objects that have implemented or inherited different interfaces and classes.

I would start with Strict at first and if it starts getting in your way then drop down to Explicit. But don't ever both turn off, that way lies madness and excessive debugging time.

Over the years with VB I pretty much use Double for all floating point variables. This way you avoid many problems with rounding and loss of accuracy. In VB6 I used long as it was a 32-bit integer, but Integer work just as well in .NET as it is a Int32. I also recommend using Int32, Int16, etc instead of Integer,Long, etc in case Microsoft ever decides to redefine those keywords.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to disagree with [RS Conley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222370/option-strict-on-and-net-for-vb6-programmers/222693#222693) (very unusual). My favourite VB6 gurus - Francesco Balena, Dan Appleman - all disliked VB6's automatic conversion, and are [in](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00008I9N4) [favour](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Practical-Guidelines-Practices-Developers-Pro-Developer/dp/0735621721) of `Option Strict` in .NET. Many experienced VB6 programmers know automatic conversion as "evil type coercion" ([pdf](http://vb.mvps.org/articles/pt199511.pdf)), and will be delighted to switch on `Option Strict`.

It's occasionally better to use one small module without `Option Strict`, to avoid lots of complicated reflection code. But that's the exception that proves the rule.

Answer (score 2):

Given Boehm's notion that fixing a problem earlier in the development cycle consumes the least resources, I'm a fan of every tool that helps developers "get it right" as early as possible.  For this reason, I'm an advocate of things like IntelliSense that is both an efficiency boost as well as a tool that helps you implement working code earlier in the cycle.  (Working, but not *necessarily* correct.)

For this reason, I also support the use of Option Strict as a way to help keep missteps and the consequent corrections deep into "design time."

Answer (score 0):

If you're used to having your types checked, then you probably want option strict on.  turning it off can have advantages, but if your brain isn't tuned to spotting errors where your compiler would usually complain, then I would say to leave it on. I've worked in VB.Net a lot, and I have to say, that even though I work with options strict turned off most of the time, I've seen plenty of situations where having it turned on would have prevented quite a few bugs.

Comment: Hmmm - maybe you should consider turning Option Strict on?!?

Comment: Yes, I would, but in my current project, fixing all the errors by turning options strict on would probably take months.