# The difference between + and & for joining strings in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, string

What is the difference between `+` and `&` for joining strings in VB.NET?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

There's no difference if both operands are strings. However, if one operand is a string, and one is a number, then you run into problems, see the code below.

```
"abc" + "def" = "abcdef"
"abc" & "def" = "abcdef"
"111" + "222" = "111222"
"111" & "222" = "111222"
"111" & 222 = "111222"
"111" + 222 = 333
"abc" + 222 = conversion error
```

Therefore I recommend to always use `&` when you mean to concatenate, because you might be trying to concatenate an integer, float, decimal to a string, which will cause an exception, or at best, not do what you probably want it to do.

Comment: Or always enforce Option Strict On, in which case you never need to worry about it.  Option Strict On has numerous other advantages as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222370/option-strict-on-and-net-for-vb6-programmers

Comment: There is a problem with `&` for string concatenation. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te2585xw.aspx) "The & operator always widens its operands to String, regardless of the setting of Option Strict". So for example `"Hello " & 2.5` will silently convert the 2.5 to a string using the regional settings (you might get `"2.5"` or `"2,5"`). Fine if that was what you wanted. I would much, much rather be forced to specify explicitly.

Comment: @MarkJ Oh yeah, that regional stuff can really get you if you don't watch it.  Especially on web servers.  If you have a bunch of web servers, you should make sure they are all configured to the same regional settings, lets you get wierd formatting problems with numbers and dates.

Comment: For completeness, it should also be worth noting what is returned when you perform `"abc" & 222` (`"abc222"`).

Comment: Let me mention that `333` in the next-to-last line is actually of type `System.Double`.

Answer (score 14):

The & operator always makes sure that both operands are strings, while the + operator finds the overload that matches the operands.

The expression `1 & 2` gives the value "12", while the expression 1 + 2 gives the value 3.

If both operands are strings, there is no difference in the result.

Comment: + operator only carries out implicit conversion if `Option Strict` is `Off`. But & operator will carry out implicit conversion to string regardless of the `Option Strict` setting. [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te2585xw.aspx) "The & operator always widens its operands to String, regardless of the setting of Option Strict". So for example `"Hello " & 2.5` will silently convert the 2.5 to a string using the regional settings (you might get `"2.5"` or `"2,5"`). Fine if that was what you wanted.

Answer (score 12):

None.

As you can see below. These two lines of code compiles exactly to the same CIL code:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim s1 As String = "s1"
        Dim s2 As String = "s2"
        s2 += s1
        s1 &= s2
    End Sub

End Module
```

Compiles to (note `System.String::Concat`):

```
.method public static void  Main() cil managed
{
.entrypoint
.custom instance void [mscorlib]System.STAThreadAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 )
// Code size       31 (0x1f)
.maxstack  2
.locals init ([0] string s1,
       [1] string s2)
IL_0000:  nop
IL_0001:  ldstr      "s1"
IL_0006:  stloc.0
IL_0007:  ldstr      "s2"
IL_000c:  stloc.1
IL_000d:  ldloc.1
IL_000e:  ldloc.0
IL_000f:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(string,
                                                          string)
IL_0014:  stloc.1
IL_0015:  ldloc.0
IL_0016:  ldloc.1
IL_0017:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(string,
                                                          string)
IL_001c:  stloc.0
IL_001d:  nop
IL_001e:  ret
} // end of method Module1::Main
```

Comment: Thanks Aliostad, that sums it up perfectly. I was most curious (and probably should have outlined it a bit better in my question) to how it was handled. String + String (as long as they're both strings) is the same as String & String (regardless of a complex set of rules with the + operator).

Comment: No probs. It is always good to have a look at the IL code using ILDASM. Initially it is unfamiliar but gradually you get used to it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference in most of the cases. However, the best practice is:

"+" should be reserved for *integer additions*, because if you don't use **Option Strict On** then you might have really messed up situations such as:

`Input + 12` might give you `20` instead of `812`. This can be especially bad in an ASP.NET application where the input comes from POST/GET.

Simply put: **For joining strings, always use "&" instead of "+".**

*Obviously, use [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) where it's suitable :)*

Answer (score 3):

The + operator can be either addition or concatenation.  The & is only concatenation.  If the expressions are both strings the results would be the same.

I use & when working with strings, and + when working with numbers, so there is never confusion about my intent.  If you mistakenly use + and one expression is a string and one is a number, you run the risk of un-desired results.

Answer (score 2):

If both of the types are statically typed to [System.String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx), there is zero difference between the code. Both will resolve down to the [String.Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khca9w90.aspx) member (this is what `+` does for strings).

However, if the objects are not strongly typed to string, Visual Basic late binding will kick in and go two very different routes. The `+` version will attempt to do an *add* operation which literally tries to add the objects. This will do all manner of attempts to convert both values to a number and then add them.

The `&` operator will attempt to concatenate. The Visual Basic runtime will go through all manner of conversions to convert both values to strings. It will then `String.Concat` the results.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that the `&` operator **disregards Option Strict**. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te2585xw.aspx) "The & operator always widens its operands to String, regardless of the setting of Option Strict". So for example `"Hello " & 2.5` will silently convert the 2.5 to a string using the regional settings (you might get `"2.5"` or `"2,5"`). Fine if that was what you wanted. Contrast with `+` which is strict when `Option Strict On`

Answer (score 1):

Straight from MSDN Documentation: [Concatenation Operators in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te2585xw.aspx)

> Differences Between the Two Concatenation Operators
>
> The + Operator (Visual Basic) has the primary purpose of adding two
>   numbers. However, it can also concatenate numeric operands with string
>   operands. The + operator has a complex set of rules that determine
>   whether to add, concatenate, signal a compiler error, or throw a
>   run-time InvalidCastException exception.
>
> The & Operator (Visual Basic) is defined only for String operands, and
>   it always widens its operands to String, regardless of the setting of
>   Option Strict. The & operator is recommended for string concatenation
>   because it is defined exclusively for strings and reduces your chances
>   of generating an unintended conversion.

Do trust MSDN! :-)

Answer (score 0):

None when joining strings:

```
    Dim string1 As String = "A" + "B"
    Dim string2 As String = "A" & "B"

    If string1.Equals(string2) And string2.Equals(string1) Then
        Debugger.Break()
    End If
```