# FindControl in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, findcontrol

I'm trying to find a control in a page. The Id is available as a server control (CheckBox)
This throws exception "not able to convert string to double"

```
Dim taskId As HtmlInputCheckBox
i =10
taskId = Me.FindControl("chkTaskOption_" + i)
taskId.Checked = True
```

Can any one tell me where i'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you need to use `&` instead of `+` to concatenate two strings in VB.NET.  Change this line:

```
taskId = Me.FindControl("chkTaskOption_" & i)
```

For further reading, there's a good discussion about this in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088053/vb-net-string-manipulation-or).

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the cast no? Sorry, just saw the "double" part

Comment: Once the string part is resolved, I'm sure a cast will be needed to set the Checked to True.

Comment: VB.NET does not actually require the explicit type conversion in the above situation -- it will work fine as long as the control it finds actually is an HtmlInputCheckBox (or some derivative of it). He's setting the Checked property on his local variable which is of the right type, so there will be no error on that line.

Comment: Unless you have Option Strict turned on, that is (which it is not by default). Then you would need the explicit conversion.

Answer (score 2):

You might just be missing a cast of the type returned from FindControl. Or on the variable i.  I can't remember if VB.net will convert for you.

```
i =10
Dim taskId As HtmlInputCheckBox
taskId = CType(Me.FindControl("chkTaskOption_" & i.ToString()), HtmlInputCheckBox)
taskId.Checked = True
```

Comment: Does VB.NET support the AS syntax that C# does? You could also use CheckBox instead of HtmlInputCheckBox I think ...

Comment: Added a fix, patmortech has it though. Had to look it up myself.