# VB.NET: Convert string containing "Lastname, Firstname" to "Firstname Lastname"

Tags: vb.net, string

I'm trying to convert a string that contains someones name as "Last, First" to "First Last".

This is how I am doing it now:

```
name = name.Trim
name = name.Substring(name.IndexOf(",") + 1, name.Length) & " " & name.Substring(0, name.IndexOf(",") - 1)
```

When I do this I get the following error:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
>
> Index and length must refer to  a location within the string
>
> Parameter name: length

Can someone explain why I am getting this error and how I should be doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting error on this:

```
name.Substring(name.IndexOf(",") + 1, name.Length)
```

`name.Length` should have subtracted with the length of the string *before the comma*.

The best way for that is to split the string.

```
Dim oFullname as string = "Last, First"
Dim oStr() as string = oFullname.split(","c)
oFullname = oStr(1).trim & " " & oStr(0).trim
MsgBox (oFullname)
```

Comment: Slightly related - what is the 'c' for as part of your split call?  I haven't seen that before (until now, in all of the answers to this question.)

Comment: It converts string to character.

Comment: @HillBilly.Developer The separator in this case is an instance of the `Char` data type; thus it is appended with the literal type character `c`.

Answer (score 1):

simply ,you only need to split the string

```
Dim originalName As String = "Last,First"
Dim parts = name.Split(","C)
Dim name As String = parts(1) & "  " & parts(0)
```

Comment: I won't downvote you because your answer is wrong. IN Vb.net, concactenation of the string don't use `+` but instead `&`

Comment: @johntotetwoo His answer is in fact correct you can use both + and & to concactenate strings in [Vb.net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te2585xw(v=VS.71).aspx). &, is the recommended one to use for strings, but both work

Comment: @MarkHall yes , you can use both, but & is more recommended ,check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088053/vb-net-string-manipulation-or

Comment: @sleimanjneidi Won't this put it back in FirstName LastName order? OP wanted it the other way around!

Comment: oops sorry, didn't have a compiler here. you are both correct. :(

Comment: @sleimanjneidi I stated so in my Comment, all I was saying is that it is not **wrong** to use +

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter for [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) is the length of the substring, not the end position. For this reason, you're always going to go out of bounds if you do `str.Substring(n, str.Length)` with n > 0 (which would be the whole point of a substring).

You need to subtract `name.IndexOf(",") + 1` from `name.Length` in your first substring. Or just split the string, as the others have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Unix command line--like the terminal on a Mac--you can do it like this:

Let's say that you have a file containing your last-comma-space-first type names like this:

```
Last1, First1
Last2, First2
Last3, First3
```

OK, now let's save it as `last_comma_space_first.txt`. At this point you can use this command I came up with for your particular problem:

```
sed -E 's/([A-Za-z0-9]+), ([A-Za-z0-9]+)/\2 \1/g' last_comma_space_first.txt > first_space_last.txt
```

--->>> Scroll --->>>

You're done! Now, go check that `first_space_last.txt` file! ^_^ You should get the following:

```
First1 Last1
First2 Last2
First3 Last3
```

Tell your friends... Or don't...

Answer (score 0):

This would work keeping to the posters format.

```
Name = "Doe,John"
Name = Replace(Name.Substring(Name.IndexOf(","), Name.Length - Name.IndexOf(",")) & " " & Name.Substring(0, Name.IndexOf(",")), ",", "")
```

Result Name = "John Doe"