# Concatenating string to integer

Tags: vb.net

Please see the code below:

```
Dim str1 As String="Test"
Dim int1 As Integer = 1
Dim str2 = str1 & int1
```

Should int1 be casted into a string before it is concatenated or does it make no difference?

I have recently turned OPTION STRICT ON in a VB.NET app

Comment: Why don't you try and find out? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very poor question but I'll answer it anyway. The result is: no, casting is not needed. In your case `str2` will be `Test1`.

Internally the code will use [**String.Concat()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Concat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, which takes objects and calls `ToString()` on the object. And since everything in .NET derives from `object`, this will work.

Answer (score 2):

See [String manipulation with & or + in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1088175/3453226).

> Using the **&** operator indicates your intention to concatenate strings,
>   while the **+** operator indicates your intention to add numbers. Using
>   the **&** operator will convert both sides of the operation into strings.

**`&` always returns *String*.**

Answer (score 0):

The [concatenation (&) operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6hxk86b.aspx) can convert a number to a string implicitly.

In addition, If I had any doubts I would use [TypeName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5422sfdf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to determine the type of the variable 
In your case:

```
 TypeName(str2)
```

Also, If [Option Strict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) is on, the implicit [narrowing conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1e94s7e.aspx) causes a compile-time error, In this case it is Widening conversion.

Comment: or just hold your mouse over it to see the Type