# String concatenation: using += vs. &=

Tags: vb.net, string-concatenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The difference between + and & for joining strings in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734600)

In VB.NET you can use either `+=` or `&=` to concatenante a string (ignoring using a StringBuilder for this question -- this is directed at a very simple concatenation).

What are the differences (if any) of using one or the other in VB.NET?