# Concatenate text with Eval

Tags: asp.net, webforms

How to concatenate static text in the start of `Eval("")` in asp.net?

Answer (score 64):

try...

```
Text='<%# "Mr " + Eval("FirstName") + " " + Eval("LastName")%>'
```

Comment: I got a string-to-double conversion error when I did this, but it worked after I changed the first '+' to '&'.

Comment: @user910683 I'm guessing you were using VB (not C#) in which yes, to more reliably concatenate values into a string, you should use `&` -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734600/the-difference-between-and-for-joining-strings-in-vb-net

Answer (score 20):

For concating two fields from db you can use string.Concat function in eval()

```
 Text='<%# string.Concat(Eval("FirstName"), " ", Eval("LastName"))%>'
```

Answer (score 2):

try this: 
Text='<%# string.Concat("Table No:", " ", Eval("table_no")) %>'

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
<%#Class.something.ToString() & Eval("something_to_eval")%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this (without single quote) worked for me. And Visual Studio underlines it as a Validation warning.

```
 onclick=<%# "modCbClick('#tbl_" + Eval("ModCode") + "', this)" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good method I am using whereby I want to Concatenate a string to an Eval and use in the CommandArgument of a LinkButton.

Append string to start

```
CommandArgument='<%# String.Format(string.Concat("TextString", Eval("DBValue")))%>'
```

Append string to end

```
CommandArgument='<%# String.Format(string.Concat(Eval("DBValue"), "TextString"))%>'
```