# How I can concat two values inside a id of a list

Tags: c#

How can I concatenate two strings in a id of a unordered list. The problem is :

```
<li id='autor<%# Eval("id") %>' runat="server"/>
```

What I have inside of `<%# Eval("id") %>` is the id of the author I and want in my id the string autor plus the id.

How can I do that?.

With the id it's different than the Text, so I don't know how to do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concatenate two or more strings in inline code ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668947/concatenate-two-or-more-strings-in-inline-code-asp-net)

Comment: Duplicate `'<%# "Mr " + Eval("FirstName") + " " + Eval("LastName")%>'`
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100716/concatenate-text-with-eval

Comment: It's no duplicate because this is with the Text no with Id, With Id this not works,

Comment: you simply need typecasting. and try to google your question before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it using:

```
<li id='<%# "Author"+ Eval("id") %>' runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
'<%# "Mr " + Eval("ID") & Eval("LastName")%>
```