# Concatenate Eval with text inside a Label

Tags: c#, gridview, eval

I have a label inside a gridview, the ds_Value for that record is 10...how can i insert a text along side with the eval variable

```
<asp:GridView ...
    <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lb" Text='Val: <%# Eval("ds_Value") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>        
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
...
```

- The Result is "Val: "
- I want "Val: 10"

Comment: sorry, i dont understood your suggestion

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100716/concatenate-text-with-eval

Comment: That's it...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
Text='<%# "Mr " + Eval("FirstName") + " " + Eval("LastName")%>'
```