# How to structure TextBox Placeholder Syntax

Tags: asp.net

The following works and displays the users User Name as a placeholder in the textbox but I can't figure out how to put the word "Username: " before it so that it reads.. Username: John

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" style="margin-top:-8px;" runat="server" Placeholder='<%# Eval("UserName") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="2" Columns="34"></asp:TextBox>
```

I tried this..

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" style="margin-top:-8px;" runat="server" Placeholder='"Username: " & <%# Eval("UserName") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="2" Columns="34"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: You tried that but havent mentioned the result

Comment: gives me a sytax error

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100716/concatenate-text-with-eval

Comment: Placeholder='<%# "Username: " & Eval("UserName") %>'  THIS WORKS, THANK YOU!