# How to retrieve SQL Query (last record id) + Execute it in ASP.NET & concatenate (append/prepend) it with a String

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I'm trying to retrieve the last ID, in a table, using SQL query and then append the result together with a TextBox value (which is a String):

```vb
Dim searchforID = New OleDbCommand("select ID from [table1] where ID = (select max(id) from [table1])", con)
Dim variable1 = searchforID + TextBox1.Text
```

But it throws this error:

> Compiler Error Message: BC30452: Operator '+' is not defined for types
>   'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand' and 'String'.

### Trying to fix it

-- So i tried to convert the returned record ID like this:

```vb
Dim variable1 = Convert.ToString(searchforID) + TextBox1.Text
```

There is no error now but unfortunately the result returned is "System.Data.OleDb.OleDb" + the textbox value, as this example:
**System.Data.OleDb.OleDbtest**

-- I too thought to convert the returned record ID to integer throws an error:

> Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object
>   of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand' to type
>   'System.IConvertible'.

#### So why does retrieving the last record ID fail? Might my SQL query be false?

Thank you.

---

## So straight forward solution for problem if someone may find it useful:

```asp
Dim searchforID = New OleDbCommand("select MAX(ID) from [table1]", con)
Dim variable1 = searchforID.ExecuteScalar() & TextBox1.Text
```

Also the answers and comments below have useful information.

Comment: you cant do like this.  You need to return Id from table using execute scalar command

Comment: `searchforID` is an `OleDbCommand` which you must execute against the database. You must retrieve the _result_ of the query, not the query itself.

Comment: @AshReva You hit the point. I understand that ExecuteScalar is good for a one result, do you know if there are other methods than ExecuteScalar that do the same job too?

Comment: @JohnWillemse Thanks so much, this makes sense, so the _Command_ (searchforID) is actually the query and I must execute this _command_ to return a readable result (string). is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's how it works. The two answers to your question explain this in detail and give good examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim cmd = New OleDbCommand("select MAX(ID) from [table1]", con)
Dim variable1 = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString() & TextBox1.Text
```

First, if you have command, you should **execute** the command. There are several ways to execute a `DbCommand`, depending the type of the command.

Second, if you want the maximum id, go straight and query the maximum! The nested subquery is redundant.

Third, using `&` to concatenate strings is safer than `+`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/734600/1174942) for more information.

Comment: Thank you, ExecuteScalar() is just what it needed to work. Thank you anyway for the additional information: 1) about seeing result in the textbox, 2) about converting result to string.

Comment: But i have 2 questions please. is there a difference between `cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()` and `Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar())`. Plus, I see there's no `cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToInt()` any idea why? Thank you.

Comment: @compliance There is actually no difference between them. `ToString` method is available on all the objects. There can be always a reason to convert some object to its string representation. This is not true for `int`. Converting to integer does **not** alwasy has a meaning. Also it may not be alwasy successful.

Comment: Ok. Thank you too for the straight forward query.

Comment: Oh, that method before you edited it was a good information too (how to return result as a textbox value), anyway i thought why not add the following regarding converting types: i found `ctype(myVar, dataType)` so in my case, _if i need to convert_, i can convert command type like this `CType(searchforID.ExecuteScalar(), String)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim variable1 = searchforID.ExecuteScalar() & TextBox1.Text
```

searchforID is ICommand, not a value, if you want to get a result, you need to execute the command and get result. ExecuteScalar returns first cell value of the first row from query

Comment: Thanks so much, there was no need to convert, just adding this `ExecuteScalar` did the job, I wouldn't know that. But if I understand it right, is the type of the result returned with `ExecuteScalar` a String? In other words does it automatically convert the Command type to a string value to be able to work with?

Comment: @ArsentMkrt I would like to add something, please replace `+` in the answer with `&`. As I notice, with `+` an error is thrown `Input string was not in a correct format` unless i either use the ampersand `&` either i keep `+` but I convert searchforID command (as in Unicorn's answer).

Comment: also i wish i could mark two answers, yours is just what i need to get rid of the error and straight forward, but i thought to go with the other answer for the additional information (although i didn't need to return result to textbox).

Comment: @compliance, oops yes sorry, I am c# guy, that was the reason of my misprint. no problem about the answer ;)

Comment: don't be sorry about the ampersand, thanks for your help so much. pst, i see we can't use `;` in VB.