# Why it is producing the error "expression required"?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Why it is producing the error "expression required"?

```
Public Class WinApp

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub buttonSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles buttonSubmit.Click
        MessageBox.Show("Hello" + ' ' + "how are you");
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: ok fine where you are getting that error?

Comment: That is because you are trying to mix vb.net and c# code.

Comment: #suji, I'm getting the error 'expression required' by the + operator

Comment: The correct vb.net code would be: `MessageBox.Show("Hello" + " " + "how are you")`

Comment: Thanx #Pradeep Kumar

Comment: @Pradeep Kumar: No, the correct VB.NET code would be: `MessageBox.Show("Hello" & " " & "how are you")`. `+` is recommended to _not_ be used as it's only made for integers. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/734631/3740093

Comment: @Visual Vincent, The view expressed in that post may be personal opinion of the author. It doesn't matter whether you use + or & for string concatenation. However best practices include using `OPTION STRICT ON` that would take care of the concerns expressed in that post.

Comment: @Pradeep Kumar: The `+` will convert the strings into integers before concatenating them anyway. So I guess you're right. It really doesn't matter as long as you don't want to concatenate integers as strings and described in the post. _But I'd recommend to use the `&` concatenation operator._

Comment: @VisualVincent - The `+` operator will most certainly _not_ convert the strings to integers in that code.  It may well attempt to convert the string to an integer if an integer is included in the expressions, e. g. `"Hello" + 4`.  But `Option Strict On` should catch this, but I agree with you that for string concatenation the `&` operator should be used.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run app in c# open the c# application .
You are opening vb.net project and asking c# code :)
Actual code for concatenate is given below in `c#`

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello" + ' ' + "how are you");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`MessageBox.Show("Hello" + " " + "how are you")` is the VB.net code .. you're mixing it with some other code C# or C++ code etc.