# How to format integer as string with 2 digits?

Tags: vb.net, format

I would like to format an integer 9 to "09" and 25 to "25".

How can this be done?

Comment: [Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score -8, accepted):

I don't know the exact syntax.  But in any language, it would look like this.

```
a = 9
aString =""

if a < 10 then 
  aString="0" + a 
else 
  aString = "" + a
end if
```

Comment: @user19127 : This is _**definiately not failsafe!**_ One should never use the `+` operator when concatenating strings with numbers. Use the `&` operator for proper AND failsafe concatenation. **See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/734631/3740093**

Answer (score 18):

You can use either of these options:

**The "0" Custom Specifier**

- `value.ToString("00")`
- `String.Format("{0:00}", value)`

**The Decimal ("D") Standard Format Specifier**

- `value.ToString("D2")`
- `String.Format("{0:D2}", value)`

For more information:

- [Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#Specifier0)
- [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#DFormatString)

Answer (score 1):

If its just leading zero's that you want, you can use this:

```
value.tostring.padleft("0",2)
value.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');   // C#
```

If you have 2 digits, say 25 for example, you will get "25" back....if you have just one digit, say 9 for example, you will get "09"....It is worth noting that this gives you a string back, and not an integer, so you may need to cast this later on in your code.

Answer (score 0):

String formate is the best way to do that. It's will only add leading zero for a single length.  9 to "09" and 25 to "25".

```
String.format("%02d", value)
```

**Bonus:**
If you want to add multiple leading zero 9 to "0009" and 1000 to "1000". That's means you want a string for 4 indexes so the condition will be %04d.

```
String.format("%04d", value)
```