# VB.Net concatenation syntax

Tags: vb.net, syntax, concatenation

Around the we i have seen a lot of code written with these opcodes; `+=` and `&=` 
I know that they are related to concatenation. So can someone explain to me what is the difference between `+=` and `&=` compared to `+` and `&`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `+=` is addition.  SImpler than `var = var +  1`;  `&` is used for strings, `&=` would be for a small loop to concat some values to a longer string

Comment: In addition to Plutonix's comment, `+` _CAN_ be used for String concatenation but is **not recommended** as it may cause exceptions in certain cases. `&` should always be used for String concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+=` operator is short form of `X = X + Y` The `+` operator is usually used for summing number rather than string combination([See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734600/the-difference-between-and-for-joining-strings-in-vb-net)). Example:

```
'Setting Values
Dim Var As Integer
Var = 101
'Adding 62 to this number (SHORT FORM)
Var += 62 'This will set Var to 163
'Reset value
Var = 101
'This is standard long form
Var = Var + 62 'This will again set Var to 163
```

The `&=` operator is short form of `String1 = String1 & String2` The `&` operator is string combination. Example:

```
'Setting Values
Dim String1 As String
String1 = "coding is "
'combine "Great" to this string (SHORT FORM)
String1 += "Great!" 'This will set String1 to "coding is Great!"
'Reset Value
String1 = "coding is "
'This is standard long form
String1 = String1 & "Great!" 'This will again set String1 to "coding is Great!"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no difference, it is just longer to write this

```
MyString = MyString & "some text"
```

than this

```
MyString &= "some text"
```

Since programmers are very lazy persons...

Same for the plus symbol for numbers. (I know it can also be used for strings but it is not recommanded...)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the OP question:  `So can someone explain to me what is the difference between += and &=`

Comment: ...compared to + and &.