# Add Subfolder names to Listview

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have Combobox, and I select folder names in It. This folder has to be searched first. In these folders are also folders named "Versions"- and these folders have another folders which I need to add on Listview. I tried this but nothing is added to my Listview:

```
Dim Folder_To_Search As String() = IO.Directory.GetDirectories("D:\", MyCombo.Text, System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

            For Each folder As String In Folder_To_Search
               ListView1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(folder + "\Versions\"))
            Next
```

I guess I'm missing something after + "\Versions\", can somebody give me a clue ?

Comment: `Path.GetFileName()` gets the file name from the string passed - you are passing a path or partial path.  Are you trying to get the filenames from that path?

Comment: @Plutonix yes, foldernames from e.g. D:\Microsoft\Versions\...

Comment: Please don't concatenate strings with the plus (`+`), it is mainly the addition operator. VB.NET uses the ampersand (`&`) as its native concatenation operator. By using it you will avoid getting into problems such as the ones described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/734631/3740093).

Comment: @VisualVincent, thanks for info. I just need get this working so I tried with "+". "&" doesn't work either though....

Comment: Sorry for being unclear... It wasn't your problem in this case, but by using the ampersand instead you avoid future problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is being added to your listview because GetDirectories returns, as its name implies, *directories*. So you're getting your list of directories and then using Path.GetFilename on each of them, but the directories do not have a filename at the end of them so only empty strings are being added to your listview.

---

Edit for Comment: Then it sounds like you need to run basically two nested directory searches; the first one for folders like "Microsoft" and the second for "Versions" within Microsoft folders, then loop through and get the files:

```
    Dim TopLevelDirectories As String() = IO.Directory.GetDirectories("D:\", "*" & MyCombo.Text & "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    For Each tlDir As String In TopLevelDirectories
        Dim SubLevelDirectories As String() = IO.Directory.GetDirectories(tlDir, "*Versions*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        For Each slDir As String In SubLevelDirectories
            Dim dInfo As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(slDir)
            Dim fInfo() As FileInfo = dInfo.GetFiles
            For Each f As FileInfo In fInfo
                ListView1.Items.Add(f.FullName) 'or ListView1.Items.Add(f.Name)
            Next
        Next
    Next
```

If I understand your goal correctly, the code above should find all the files you're looking for. I made some test folders and threw Microsoft/Versions in at different levels of the directories and this code picked them all up

Comment: thanks for reply and explanation. I see your point now. However your code doesn't work. I didn't quite elaborate: "Microsoft" isn't located in "D:\Microsoft" only, It can be located in "D:\SomeFolder\Microsoft\" too. So folder Microsoft must be searched first, that's why I use SearchOption.Alldirectories. Combobox concatenation like yours doesn't do that.

Comment: Can't you search for the location of "Microsoft" first and then put the location in a variable and then carry on with the code in the answer?

Comment: I misunderstood your goal, I've edited the code and I think it will work for what you're trying to accomplish now