# How do I add text to a textbox? Not replace

Tags: vb.net

I'd like to know how to add text to a textbox by the use of an event, for example the click of a button.

Now when I say add I literally mean add, not replace.

Not `TextBox1.Text = ""` because all that does it change all the text in the textbox to whatever is in the quotes, I want to add text not replace it so for example if I had "ABC" typed into my textbox and I want to add the letter "D" to it without replacing the whole text what would I have to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a string to keep track of it and add that string to the text box.

Comment: Are you in asp.net or WinForms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [**concatenation operator**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te2585xw.aspx) to concatenate your new text with the old one:

```
TextBox1.Text &= "D" 'Results in "ABCD"
```

or use the [**`TextBox.AppendText()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
TextBox1.AppendText("D") 'Also results in "ABCD"
```

---

Note that my first example is the same as doing:

```
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "D"
```

Also see [**this Stack Overflow answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/734631/3740093) about why you should always concatenate strings with the ampersand (`&`) instead of the plus sign (`+`).