# Read txt and add in richtexbox

Tags: vb.net

This Code

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\.minecraft\logs\latest.log",
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\.minecraft\logs\latestc.log")

        Using reader As New StreamReader(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\.minecraft\logs\latestc.log")
            While Not reader.EndOfStream
                Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
                If line.Contains("Setting user: ") Then
                    Dim lastpart As String = line.Substring(line.LastIndexOf(": ") + 1)
                    FlatAlertBox3.Text = lastpart
                    Exit While
                End If
            End While
        End Using
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(
            Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\.minecraft\logs\latestc.log")

    End Sub
```

I want to this name http://prntscr.com/omml8w in richtextbox1.text like up code , but its not work , its add only first name not all names ,i want all names add in richtextbox  up code , how can i do this plzz help me ^_^

Comment: First of all you are replacing the text in the text box, causing it to be overwritten each time. You need to _append_ the names. -- Possible duplicate of [How do I add text to a textbox? Not replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39797892/how-do-i-add-text-to-a-textbox-not-replace)

Comment: In addition to that, also remove `Exit While` as that stops the loop after the first entry has been found (hence why you only get the first name).

Comment: Rather than calling `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`  four times, call it once and assign to a string variable. Then use that vaiable with `Path.Combine()`.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, you need to append `lastpart` to the contents of the text box, and remove the `Exit While` which forces exiting the loop on the first iteration.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim appDataFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(
        appDataFolder & "\.minecraft\logs\latest.log",
        appDataFolder & "\.minecraft\logs\latestc.log")

    Using reader As New StreamReader(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\.minecraft\logs\latestc.log")
        ' Set text box to empty string.
        FlatAlertBox3.Text = ""
        While Not reader.EndOfStream
            Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
            If line.Contains("Setting user: ") Then
                Dim lastpart As String = line.Substring(line.LastIndexOf(": ") + 1)
                ' Append to contents of text box.
                FlatAlertBox3.Text += lastpart
                'Exit While
            End If
        End While
    End Using
    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(appDataFolder & "\.minecraft\logs\latestc.log")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim AppData As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
    Dim logs As String = Path.Combine(AppData, ".minecraft\logs")
    Dim templog As String = Path.Combine(logs, "latestc.log")

    File.Copy(Path.Combine(logs, "latest.log"), templog, True)

    Dim settings = File.ReadLines(templog).
        Where(Function(line) line.Contains("Setting user: "))

    FlatAlertBox3.Text = String.Join(vbCrLf, settings)

    File.Delete(templog)
End Sub
```

Make sure to use `Imports System.IO` at the top of the file. I might also add a `Try/Finally` to be sure the `File.Delete()` runs.

For fun, we can write this as a one-liner:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load   
    FlatAlertBox3.Text = String.Join(vbCrLf, File.ReadLines(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), ".minecraft\logs\latest.log")).Where(Function(line) line.Contains("Setting user: ")))  
End Sub
```

Though I'd never use unreadable code like that in production.