# Not read text file correct

Tags: vb.net

I want when I read txt file and add in ListBox1.items, add this text http://prntscr.com/on12e0 correct text §eUltra §8[§716x§8].zip not like this http://prntscr.com/on11kv

My code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim appDataFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(
    appDataFolder & "\.minecraft\logs\latest.log",
    appDataFolder & "\.minecraft\logs\latestc.log")

    Using reader As New StreamReader(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\.minecraft\logs\latestc.log")


        While Not reader.EndOfStream
            Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
            If line.Contains(" Reloading ResourceManager: Default,") Then
                Dim lastpart As String = line.Substring(line.LastIndexOf(", ") + 1)

                ListBox1.Items.Add(lastpart)
            End If
        End While
    End Using
    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(appDataFolder & "\.minecraft\logs\latestc.log")
End Sub
```

Comment: The paragraph character is not shown properly. Open the file `latestc.log` in Visual Studio in binary mode and take a look at hex code of the paragraph-character. What do you see there ? What is the encoding of the file (UTF-8, UTF-16 ..) ?

Comment: Almost the same as your previous question: [Read txt and add in richtexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57297064/719186)

Answer (score 0):

This question is only different from your first question in that your have substituted a ListBox for a RichTextBox. It seems you got perfectly acceptable answers to your first question. But I will try again.

First get the path to the file. I don't know why you are copying the file so I didn't.

Add Imports System.IO to the top of your file. The you can use the File class methods. `File.ReadAllLines` returns an array of strings.

Next use Linq to get the items you want. Don't update the user interface on each iteration of a loop. The invisible Linq loop just adds the items to an array. Then you can update the UI once with `.AddRange`.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim appDataFolder = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "\.minecraft\logs\latest.log")
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(appDataFolder)
    Dim lstItems = (From l In lines
                    Where l.Contains(" Reloading ResourceManager: Default,")
                    Select l.Substring(l.LastIndexOf(", ") + 1)).ToArray
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(lstItems)
End Sub
```

If this answer and the previous 2 answer you got don't work, please lets us know why.