# VB 2010 Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid

Tags: vb.net

please help me. this is a uni project and I keep getting the error "Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid." even when I made sure that everything is in the correct type, everything with a value...etc.

I want to insert some new rows in my access database, here is a picture of the table that Im trying to insert into
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVXXp.png)

and this is the code
the error appears at the select statement in the sub w()

```
Dim c As Integer
    Dim b As Double
    Dim a, d, z As String
    a = "'" + TextBox1.Text + "'"
    b = CInt(TextBox2.Text)
    c = CInt(TextBox3.Text)
    d = "'" + TextBox4.Text + "'"
    z = "'" + ComboBox1.SelectedItem + "'"


    If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "الجبيل" Then
        w("insert into employees (em_id,em_name,m_id,city,phone,salary,password)" & " values (" + 32111 + "," + a + "," + 12303 + "," + z + "," + c + "," + b + "," + d + ")")
    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "جدة" Then
        w("insert into employees (em_id,em_name,m_id,city,phone,salary,password)" & " values (" + 32111 + "," + a + "," + 12302 + "," + z + "," + c + "," + b + "," + d + ")")
    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "الرياض" Then
        w("insert into employees (em_id, em_name,m_id,city,phone,salary,password)" & " values (" + 32111 + "," + a + "," + 12301 + "," + z + "," + c + "," + b + "," + d + ")")
    End If
    MsgBox("تم إضافة السجل بنجاح")
    TextBox1.Clear()
    TextBox2.Clear()
    TextBox3.Clear()
    TextBox4.Clear()
```

the sub w("") is:

```
 Public Sub w(ByVal s As String)
    Dim cum As New OleDbCommand(s, con)
    cum.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Sub
```

problem is that it works on different forms (to diffident tables and stuff), but not in here...

what should I do?

Comment: Dont build SQL that way; use SQL parameters

Comment: How does two rather similar questions get asked with _**so**_ little time in-between??

Comment: Like Plutonix says you should _**really**_ use SQL parameters. However the actual reason to why you get the error is illustrated in [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/734631/3740093).

Comment: Why is the variable b declared as a double, then you try to convert text into an integer and assign that to it? And if there is no text in the textbox, doesn't it make sense that it's impossible to convert "nothing" to a number?

Comment: *Great* variable and method names by the way.