# How to pass multiple values through command argument in Asp.net ListView?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to pass multiple values through command argument tag in a listview. All the questions here are referring to GridView instead of a listview (I'm not sure if it makes a difference). I'm getting an error that Input String is not in correct format.

### My code is:

aspx:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="View Details" CssClass="button" CommandName="ViewApplicationDetails" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") + "|" + Eval("email") + "|" + Eval("application_hash")%>'/>
```

---

VB.NET:

```
Private Sub ListView1_ItemCommand(sender As Object, e As ListViewCommandEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemCommand
    If e.CommandName = "ViewApplicationDetails" Then
        Dim strAttributes As String()

        strAttributes = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split("|")
        'Do something 
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks fine at the first glance. What line throws the error?

Comment: the line that has asp button in it. The error is "System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format." It works fine when i keep one value in the command argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String concatenation with "+" might be unreliable at times in VB.Net. See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/734600/728795) for discussion. That could be what you are facing. Things to try instead are "&" operator:

```
Eval("id") & "|" & Eval("email") & ...
```

or String.Format (readability boost for free):

```
String.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}", Eval("id"), Eval("email"), ...)
```

Comment: Thank you Andrei. All i had to do was to use "&" instead of "+"

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try with this

String.Format method:

CommandArgument='<%# String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.id"), DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.email"), DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.application_hash")) %>'

Please let me know whether you are able to fix.