# How not to overwrite files in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to check if the current file exists at the same time save video to different file but it only overwrites to an existing file.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub ButtonVIDEO_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonVIDEO.Click

    f = New Filters
    cap = New Capture(f.VideoInputDevices(0), f.AudioInputDevices(0))
    cap.PreviewWindow = PictureBox1
    Dim Filename As String = "c:\\folder\MyFile"
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim extension As String = ".mp4"

    If ButtonVIDEO.BackColor = Color.Black Then
        cap.Filename = Filename + extension

        If File.Exists(Filename) Then
            Do
                i = i + 1
            Loop While File.Exists(Filename + i.ToString() + extension)
            Filename = Filename + i.ToString()
        End If

        cap.Cue()
        cap.Start()
        ButtonVIDEO.BackColor = Color.Red
        ButtonVIDEO.Text = "PLAYING"
        ButtonPHOTO.Hide()



    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the file name to `cap` before searching for an unsused file name.
Also, there is an error in your logic, as you are creating the full file name with `Filename + i.ToString() + extension` but you also append `i` to `Filename` itself with `Filename = Filename + i.ToString()`.
So, in then end, you are appending the number twice.

```
Private Sub ButtonVIDEO_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles ButtonVIDEO.Click

    Dim Filename As String = "c:\folder\MyFile"
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim extension As String = ".mp4"
    Dim path As String = Filename & extension

    f = New Filters
    cap = New Capture(f.VideoInputDevices(0), f.AudioInputDevices(0))
    cap.PreviewWindow = PictureBox1

    If ButtonVIDEO.BackColor = Color.Black Then
        If File.Exists(path) Then
            Do
                i = i + 1
                path = Filename & i & extension
            Loop While File.Exists(path)
        End If

        cap.Filename = path
        cap.Cue()
        cap.Start()
        ButtonVIDEO.BackColor = Color.Red
        ButtonVIDEO.Text = "PLAYING"
        ButtonPHOTO.Hide()
    End If
End Sub
```

The path should have only one backslash in `c:\folder`. In VB strings are concatenated with `&`, not `+`.

See answer to [The difference between + and & for joining strings in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/734631/880990)