# Best practice or performance difference between ToString() and & concatenation

Tags: .net, vb.net, performance, string

When I am concatenating object values together to form a string in VB.NET, is there a difference in performance or a recommended best practice between using the `&` concat or the `+` concat with calls to `.ToString()` on each object?

Example (which is faster or best practice):

```
Dim result1 As String = 10 & "em"
Dim result2 As String = 10.ToString() + "em"
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `+` in your second example, i.e. `Dim result2 As String = 10.ToString() + "em"`?

Comment: I have always used & for concatenation.  IMHO + is just confusing.  If you are doing a lot of string manipulations use stringbuilder.

Comment: BTW, ToString() is not part of VB.NET. It's part of the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no performance difference.  If you omit the `.ToString()` call explicitly the compiler will essentially just fill that in for you.  If you use Option Explicit you will be required to call the method or you'll get a compile error.  I have heard good reasons for preferring both & and + semantically, so the choice there is really up to you.

Comment: I think you mean if you use `Option Strict` you will be required to call the method?

Comment: Always use `Option Strict` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222370/option-strict-on-and-net-for-vb6-programmers

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried nor have I seen a performance test between the two and I doubt there's really a speed difference. I feel it's a better practice to use the 1st option because the .ToString() is inferred. Let the language hide that detail from you just as you would in a dynamic language.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable - meaning every time you manipulate a string, a new instance of a string object is created.

In these scenarios, to achieve better performance (and general best practice), use the `StringBuilder` class of `System.Text`.

In your example (im a C# coder, so apologize if my VB equivalent is incorrect)

```
Dim result As StringBuilder() = new StringBuilder()
result.Append("10")
result.Append("em")
Dim resultString As String = result.ToString()
```

Only when you invoke the `.ToString()` method of the `StringBuilder` object is an instance of the string created.

You should get used to using `StringBuilder` as a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use string.concat(str1, str2, str3, str4).  This is an overloaded function and will take anywhere from 2-4 string arguments.  With 3 or 4 strings to concat it is the fastest option as it is implemented to perform the concatenation in one operation which saves performance since strings are immutable.

Once you hit ~10+ strings you should use the stringbuilder class as suggested by RPM1984.

Otherwise, I suggest using '&' for string concatenations.  It saves confusion as '+' can be easily confused for integer operations.