# Populate an Array of Object Based on DataReader Data

Tags: vb.net, class, datareader

I am not sure how to phrase my question properly but I want to achieve something like this.

I have a class named Products

```
public class Products

private ID as Integer

private Name as String

Public Property ProductID()
  Get
    Return ID
  End Get
  Set(ByVal value)
    ID = value
  End Set
End Property
```

In one of my code behind pages, I am retrieving data from an SQL Command and placing the same into a datareader object.

How would I be able to declare the class so that each row in my datareader would actually be an instance of the said class?

Like for example:

```
Dim myProduct() as New Product
Dim intCnt as Integer 

While datareaderData.read()
  intCnt += 1
  myProduct(intCnt) = new Product
  myProduct(intCnt).ID = datareaderData("ID")
  myProduct(intCnt).Name = datareaderData("Name")
End While
```

When I do the same, I am getting an error "Object Reference Not Set to an Instance of an Object.

I am quite stumped on this one. Any tips greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an Arraylist or -better- a [generic List(of Product)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).
Besides i would [strongly recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222370/option-strict-on-and-net-for-vb6-programmers) to set [Option Strict On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs%28VS.80%29.aspx) in your project's Compiler Settings.

```
Dim products As New List(Of Product)
While datareaderData.read()
    Dim nextProduct As New Product
    nextProduct.ProductID = CType(datareaderData("ID"), System.Int32)
    nextProduct.Name = datareaderData("Name").ToString
    products.add(nextProduct)
End While
```