# in VB Trying to Understand Reflection.. or getting a String to be a Control

Tags: vb.net, string, casting, controls

I was looking at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4132070/1529149 about reflection..

in Particular this

```
Public Sub setProperty(ByVal obj As Object, ByVal propName As String, ByVal newValue As Object)
    Dim prop As Reflection.PropertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propName)
    If Not prop Is Nothing AndAlso prop.CanWrite Then
    prop.SetValue(obj, newValue, Nothing)
    End If
End Sub
```

But I need to enter the first variable as a string or something dynamic..

I see no point setting

```
setProperty(FixedObject, "Dynamic Property", "Dynamic Results")
```

When It would be far more powerful as

```
setProperty("Dynamic Object", "Dynamic Property", "Dynamic Results")
```

for example:

```
Dim billy As String = "Label"
Dim bob   As Integer = 1

setProperty(billy+bob, "Text", "Results")
```

Creates Label1.Text = "results"

Any help on getting something like that? (p.s. I understand I probably have to cast bob as a String somewhere, but I'm still new to VB)

Comment: If you are looking for a property on a UI component I don't believe you can do that. The code at the top is expecting a specific object(control, class etc) to be passed in and is then searching that object for a specifically named property. If you are after a UI control then you would need to loop through the Controls Collection comparing the control names against your string.

Comment: Dynamic object means creation in run time?..

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you would want to use Reflection, but this works:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim billy As String = "Label"
        Dim bob As Integer = 1
        Dim label As Object = Me.Controls(billy & bob)
        SetProperty(label, "Text", "Results")
    End Sub

    Public Sub SetProperty(obj As Object, propName As String, newValue As Object)
        Dim prop As Reflection.PropertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propName)
        If Not prop Is Nothing AndAlso prop.CanWrite Then
            prop.SetValue(obj, newValue, Nothing)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```