# Class with Dictionary as a property

Tags: vb.net

I know I am doing something really dim here because it's a really simple bit of code, but I just cannot see it.

I have a class which has a single property of type Dictionary. This class simply looks up against a database table snd stores some values in the dictionary property. Trouble is, I am getting a System.NullReferenceException on the LookupValues.Add line in the code below:

```
Public Class Lookup
    Private _LookupValues As Dictionary(Of Integer, String)

    Public Sub New(LookupToRetrieve As String)
        Dim sqlQuery As String
        sqlQuery = "SELECT * From LookupValues (NOLOCK) WHERE lookup_name = @LookupName"

        Using connection As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.PDFProcessorConnectionString)
            connection.Open()
            Using comm As New SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection)
                comm.Parameters.Add("@LookupName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = LookupToRetrieve

                Dim rs As SqlDataReader = comm.ExecuteReader
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                dt.Load(rs)

                For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                    LookupValues.Add(row.Item("lookup_value"), row.Item("lookup_text"))
                Next
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub

    Public Property LookupValues As Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
        Get
            Return _LookupValues
        End Get
        Private Set(value As Dictionary(Of Integer, String))
            _LookupValues = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

I just cannot see what is wrong here - the query returns valid data, but it will not add it to the dictionary... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: _LookupValues = New Dictionary(Of Integer, String) is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never create a Dictionary. Therefore `_LookupValues` will always be `Nothing`.

I would make `LookupValues` readonly. This means that you cannot assign it another dictionary. It does not mean that the dictionary itself is readonly.

```
Public ReadOnly Property LookupValues As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
```

You can use Visual Basic 14's ReadOnly [Auto-Implemented Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/auto-implemented-properties). I.e. you don't need to declare a backing field explicitly.

This still works:

```
LookupValues.Add(CInt(row.Item("lookup_value")), CStr(row.Item("lookup_text")))
```

I also recommend using [`Option Strict On`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/222478/880990).

Comment: See, I knew I was doing something stupid! All it needed was a 'New' in the dictionary declaration. Thanks for the help :)