# Extending aspnet_users to add additional field

Tags: asp.net, security, .net-security

I have an application that i am building in `lightswitch` and created the user roles and authentication for them. in my database, i have all `aspnet security` tables. Now in `aspnet_Users` where i have all my users and `aspnet_memebership` with relevant info. I need to add a field to either table (which ever you guys recomend) to capture additonal info, i.e Country. My intention is that when using my code in asp.net application i can get the country for a user. similar to how i can get the identity name for a user with the following code.

EDITED
I know how to add the field in the table, what i dont know is how to get to access the field using User.Identity... I would like my new field to show up in code.

sorry if there was any misunderstanding.

```
Application.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

I would like to achieve something similar for the person country like:

```
Application.Current.User.Identity.Country
```

Comment: Are you asking how to add this column to a table, or are you asking which table would be the best to add this column to?

Comment: I don't know enough about this to post an answer, but I'm 99% certain that Application.Current.User.Identity.Country will not work because it  does not exist as an object (User.Identity.Country is a pre-built object found within one of the System assemblies).  So, you will have to create this object as well as the methods that it uses to connect to your database and retrieve the data you want.  Check out these links: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386940(v=vs.110).aspx  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002323/creating-a-database-query-method/4002709#4002709

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to implement a [Custom Membership User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) along with a [Custom Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in order to access additional properties.

Then you would need to use `MembershipProvider.GetUser().Country` to retrieve the property (where `MembershipProvider` is the name of your membership provider).

If you do want to access `Application.Current.User.Identity.Country` then you could create your own class that inherits from `System.Security.Principal.IIdentity` and then cast `Application.Current.User.Identity` to your own type before accessing the property.