# Running SQL commands and getting message back

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I'm working on a project where I wish to be able to send commands to SQL Server and also run Queries. I've succeeded in returning a query to a listbox using Joel's very good tutorial here:
[creating a database query METHOD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002323/creating-a-database-query-method)

I am now trying to adapt this to execute some commands and then run a query to check the commands worked. My query is failing because I think the commands did not work.

Currently I am sending this:

```
     MySqlCommand("CREATE TABLE #CSVTest_Data" +
                  "(FirstTimeTaken DATETIME," +
                  "LatestTimeTaken DATETIME," +
                  "Market VARCHAR(50)," +
                  "Outcome VARCHAR(50),"+
                  "Odds DECIMAL(18,2)," +
                  "NumberOfBets INT," +
                  "VolumeMatched DECIMAL(18,2),"+
                  "InPlay TINYINT)");
```

Into this:

```
    private void MySqlCommand(string sql)
    {
        int numberOfRecords;
        //string result;
        using (var connection = GetConnection())
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            numberOfRecords = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        MessageBox.Show(numberOfRecords.ToString());
    }
```

My understand is that ExecuteNonQuery returns an integer of the number of rows effected. My message box shows a value of -1. Running the same command in SQL Server returns 'Command(s) completed successfully.' I would appreciate if somebody could tell me whether my MySqlCommand method looks OK and how I might return the SQL Server message that is output by running the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
var numberOfRecords = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

to

```
var numberOfRecords = command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Also, please have a look at [SqlCommand Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: That's right, I am creating a temp table. I then want to run more code to populate it, reorganise it, then insert it into the live database. Using the ExecuteScalar command I've now found that the code works to execute the commands that I want, but it seems that I cannot query a temp table. By removing the # and creating a proper table I can query it. Is there a way to query a temp table?

Comment: Yes you can. No difference e.g. `Select Count(*) from #CSVTest`

Comment: I'm finding that CREATE TABLE CSVTest_data works, but CREATE TABLE #CSVTest_data does not work when run from Visual Studio. Both work fine in SQL Server. Any ideas why?

Comment: Also, if I create the temp table in SQL Server and then run: return Query("Select Count(*) from #CSVTest_Data");, from VS, it returns 'Invalid object name '#CSVTest_Data'.

Comment: @SteveW: Yes, I suggest you to use a [stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7125bke.aspx) in this case. Which will be much easier to handle, since you can do everything in sql server

Comment: @SteveW: Let me know what is your main goal here? so can suggest you a better approach based on that

Comment: I'm building a C# app that will allow me to auto import csv data to a database (and other stuff later). Initially I worked out the commands I needed in SQL Server and liked the idea of using temp tables. As I can't seem to do that in C# I will just use proper tables and drop them after the process. I'm not sure that my program will suffer from this in any way?

Comment: @SteveW: Its not the best way (create/drop tables). Why don't use stored procedure?

Comment: I've only done a few C# tutorials and this is my first SQL project so I am new to all of this. I don't yet know what a stored procedure is, but in your previous message you said this allows you to do everything in sql server. I am not sure that is an option for me because I need to select a folder in my C# app and use that path to tell SQL server where to import the csv files from. I'm also going to need if, then, else statements.

Comment: @SteveW: If you wish to use stored procedure... You can pass the path as a [parameter](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/162/how-to-create-a-sql-server-stored-procedure-with-parameters/) and [import sql](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321686) data in the sql server

Answer (score 5):

In order to obtain messages that are output to the Messages tab in SQL Server Management Studio, "the console" when executing SQL statements on SQL Server, it is necessary to hook into the [InfoMessage event on the SqlConnection class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage.aspx):

```
using (var connection = GetConnection())
using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
    connection.InfoMessage += (s, e) =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
    };
    connection.Open();
    numberOfRecords = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Obviously you will need to handle the event differently from what I showed above, and there are other properties on the `e` parameter here as well, see [SqlInfoMessageEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlinfomessageeventargs.aspx) for details.

**NOW** having said that, bear in mind that some of the messages output to the message tab in SQL Server Management Studio is *generated* by that program, and does not originate from the server itself, so whether that particular message you're asking about would show up through that event I cannot say for sure.

Additionally, in this particular type of SQL Statement, the correct return value from `ExecuteNonQuery` is in fact -1, [as is documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. **For all other types of statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.**

*(my emphasis)*

Answer (score 2):

You Should use **ExecuteScalar**.

**ExecuteScalar** is typically used when your query returns one value.

**ExecuteNonQuery** is used for SQL statements like **update,insert,create** etc.

So change it to

```
numberOfRecords = (int)command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a comment from MSDN on `ExecuteNonQuery`:

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. ... *For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1.*

Since you are executing neither `UPDATE` nor `INSERT` nor `DELETE` - you are receiving -1 even though operation is successful. Basically you can assume that if no `SqlException` was thrown - your `CREATE` statement worked.

Comment: +Because -1 without exception is a success, you can simply make your own message and send it to your `Textbox`.

Answer (score 0):

```
numberOfRecords=(int) command.ExecuteScalar();
```