# Refactoring code for datatype

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have a common data access method as listed below. It is working fine. However, there is multiple `if blocks` based on the datatype (in the `ExecuteNonQueryWithTextCommandType`method). Also, there is too much redundant code in InsertLogSeverity method for preparing  `List<CommandParameter`>.

How to refactor this code?

**REFERENCES**

1. [How can I easily convert DataReader to List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464883/how-can-i-easily-convert-datareader-to-listt)
2. [Use of Generic Delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20681960/use-of-generic-delegates)
3. [Fastest method for SQL Server inserts, updates, selects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862428/fastest-method-for-sql-server-inserts-updates-selects)
4. [Writing a Portable Data Access Layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971568.aspx)
5. [DAL: Retrieve a DataTable using a Stored Procedure](http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/07/07/dal-retrieve-a-datatable-using-a-stored-procedure.aspx)
6. [How to improve data access layer select method Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436026/how-to-improve-data-access-layer-select-method-pattern)
7. [Return DataReader from DataLayer in Using statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850065/return-datareader-from-datalayer-in-using-statement)

**Common DAL**

```
public class MyCommonDAL
{
    public void ExecuteNonQueryWithTextCommandType(string commandText, List<CommandParameter> commandParameters)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Server=XXXX;Database=CostPage_Dev;User Id=hhhh;Password=xxxx";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.CommandText = commandText;
                command.CommandTimeout = 0;

                foreach (CommandParameter parameterDetail in commandParameters)
                {
                    if (String.Equals(parameterDetail.ParameterType, "Int"))
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameterDetail.ParameterName, Convert.ToInt32(parameterDetail.ParameterValue));
                    }
                    if (String.Equals(parameterDetail.ParameterType, "String"))
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameterDetail.ParameterName, Convert.ToString(parameterDetail.ParameterValue));
                    }
                    if (String.Equals(parameterDetail.ParameterType, "DateTime"))
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameterDetail.ParameterName, Convert.ToDateTime(parameterDetail.ParameterValue));
                    }

                }

                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Operation Specific DAL**

```
public class MyLogDAL
{

    public void InsertLogSeverity(LogSeverityTypePOCO logSeverityType)
    {
        string commandText = @"INSERT INTO dbo.LogSeverityType (LogSeverityTypeID,Name,Description,CreatedDateTime) 
                              VALUES (@LogSeverityTypeID,@Name,@Description,@CreatedDateTime)";


        List<CommandParameter> commandParameters = new List<CommandParameter>();


        CommandParameter parameter1 = new CommandParameter();
        parameter1.ParameterName = "@LogSeverityTypeID";
        parameter1.ParameterValue = logSeverityType.LogSeverityTypeID;
        parameter1.ParameterType = "Int";

        CommandParameter parameter2 = new CommandParameter();
        parameter2.ParameterName = "@Name";
        parameter2.ParameterValue = logSeverityType.Name;
        parameter2.ParameterType = "String";

        CommandParameter parameter3 = new CommandParameter();
        parameter3.ParameterName = "@Description";
        parameter3.ParameterValue = logSeverityType.Description;
        parameter3.ParameterType = "String";

        CommandParameter parameter4 = new CommandParameter();
        parameter4.ParameterName = "@CreatedDateTime";
        parameter4.ParameterValue = logSeverityType.CreatedDateTime;
        parameter4.ParameterType = "DateTime";

        commandParameters.Add(parameter1);
        commandParameters.Add(parameter2);
        commandParameters.Add(parameter3);
        commandParameters.Add(parameter4);

        MyCommonDAL dal = new MyCommonDAL();
        dal.ExecuteNonQueryWithTextCommandType(commandText, commandParameters);
    }

}
```

**Client**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyLogDAL logDAL = new MyLogDAL();

        LogSeverityTypePOCO logSeverityType = new LogSeverityTypePOCO();
        logSeverityType.LogSeverityTypeID = 107;
        logSeverityType.Name = "N";
        logSeverityType.Description = "D";
        logSeverityType.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;

        logDAL.InsertLogSeverity(logSeverityType);
    }

}
```

**DTO**

```
public class LogSeverityTypePOCO
{
    public int LogSeverityTypeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime  CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
}

public class CommandParameter
{
    public string ParameterName { get; set; }
    public object ParameterValue { get; set; }
    public string ParameterType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using your own Parameter Type and not the SqlParameter? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Reference [Writing a Portable Data Access Layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971568.aspx) and [DAL: Retrieve a DataTable using a Stored Procedure](http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/07/07/dal-retrieve-a-datatable-using-a-stored-procedure.aspx)

Comment: You are writing a Specialized DAL as you are specifically using SqlConnection and not IDbConnection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Lijo, based on my comment, and your request, I would rather make use of [SqlParamter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Something like

```
public void ExecuteNonQueryWithTextCommandType(string commandText, List<SqlParameter> commandParameters)
{
    string connectionString = @"Server=XXXX;Database=CostPage_Dev;User Id=devtopco;Password=xxxx";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = commandText;
            command.CommandTimeout = 0;
            command.Parameters.AddRange(commandParameters.ToArray());

            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Your usage would then be something like

```
string commandText = @"INSERT INTO dbo.LogSeverityType (LogSeverityTypeID,Name,Description,CreatedDateTime) 
                  VALUES (@LogSeverityTypeID,@Name,@Description,@CreatedDateTime)";
ExecuteNonQueryWithTextCommandType(commandText, new List<SqlParameter>
{
    new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "@LogSeverityTypeID", Value = logSeverityType.LogSeverityTypeID, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int},
    new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "@Name", Value = logSeverityType.Name, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar},
    new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "@Description", Value = logSeverityType.Description, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar},
    new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "@CreatedDateTime", Value = logSeverityType.CreatedDateTime, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime},
});
```

Comment: This is definitely an improvement.... Do you think it is a production usable code? Is it a wide-used pattern for data access? Or is there yet more refactoring needed here?

Comment: You should look at retrieveing the connection string from the app.config, rather than hardcoding it. Also possibly some error handling or at least logging for errors.

Comment: Yes.... Apart from that I was actually referring to `InsertLogSeverity`. Is there any scope for refactoring there?

Comment: @Lijo, see my usage specification above.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use type constraint, something like:

```
    public abstract class CommandParameter
    {
        public string ParameterName { get; set; }
        public virtual object ParameterValue { get; }
        public virtual string ParameterType { get; }
    }

    public class CommandParameter<T>:CommandParameter
    {
        public T Value { get; set; }

        public override object ParameterValue
        {
            get
            {
                return Value;
            }
        }

        public override string ParameterType
        {
            get
            {
                return typeof(T).Name;
            }
        }
    }
```

usage:

```
            var param = new CommandParameter<string>();
            param.ParameterName = "@blahblah";
            param.Value = "stringVal";

            var param2 = new CommandParameter<int>();
            param2.ParameterName = "@blahInt";
            param2.Value = 123;
```

when you need to reference the ParameterValue at a higher level, just reference the ParameterValue as it's of type Object, and not necessary to convert it.

Comment: you may use standard sqlparameter as well, and to make it concise and elegant, you could write some generic methods to do sql queries, i did one example in vb.net, here - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/25792/vb-net-sql-code-cleanup/30858#30858