# VB.NET Parsing an Object type to a GUID type

Tags: vb.net

how can I convert an object type to a GUID type in VB.NET?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you want but this might help:

```
Dim g = CType(obj, System.Guid)
```

If you want to convert a string to a `Guid`:

```
Dim g = New Guid(myString)
```

Comment: You should use `DirectCast` instead of `CType` here (or anywhere for unboxing). Here's why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102084/hidden-features-of-vbnet#103285

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to create the object as a new guid, use the following call:

```
dim objvar as guid = System.GUID.NewGuid()
```

*edit* Your question is a little unclear when you say "convert".  If you already have the object created and assigned, use DirectCast to create an object that the Visual Studio environment will recognize.

Answer (score -3):

Mehrdad's sample will work, however it is always best to declare the data type for all your variables:

```
Dim g As Guid = objectVariable
```

In this case there is no need to use CType or DirectCast.