# Is there a way to use XML Literals to view results of a Web Service call?

Tags: .net, web-services, xml-literals

I'm finding this post very useful.. 
[Hidden Features of VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102084/hidden-features-of-vb-net)

XML literals seem to be very powerful.. I'm wondering if there's any way to use them to view the results of a Web Service Call in .Net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where you are going with this but .NET abstracts away the use of XML with web services.  The typical way of interacting with web services in .NET involves using objects which are then serialized/deserialized.

So, in your program the results of the web service call will be objects and I don't see how XML literals would help you in viewing the results.  The only use I can see is if you wanted to create a new (and different) XML document from the result.

If, on the client side, you wanted to see the result as XML then you could serialize the result to XML, use a program such as Fiddler to dump the response, or use a lower level communication method (e.g. System.Net.HttpWebRequest) that gives you access to the raw XML.