# What are the differences and similarities between the .NET languages?

Tags: .net, overlap

I'm trying to figure out how much overlap there is between the different languages of the .NET framework, and what the real differences are. Is there an overlap of libraries/methods/functions...? If I'm googling a question for, say, VB .NET, and C# answers come up, what can I take from the C#-relevant info and what differences/incompatibilities should I look out for?

Comment: Just one more point I'd like to know - if there's a method that works in VB .NET (e.g. format()), can I assume that it will work in C# also? And vice versa? Or is the syntax of the libraries different as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a list of differences that claims to be complete [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/vbnet_c__difference.aspx). And wikipedia has a [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_C_Sharp_and_Visual_Basic_.NET) comparing them.

Comment: That's a great list, but it looks like it was last updated in 2005. Any significant differences since then?

Answer (score 1):

In theory, it should only be a syntactic difference, since they all get boiled down to the same runtime language. In reality, there might be some features not implemented in all languages, but I don't actually know of any.

Might be more details here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308470

Comment: Anonymous methods are one example.

Comment: (Nearly) only syntactic difference may be right for C#/VB but certainly not if you take other languages into account, such as F# that are a completely different paradigm. Using the CLR as an argument that there will be only syntactic differences is as if you would argue that *all* programming languages are just syntactic variants of each other because in the end they're executed as machine code on the CPU ...

Answer (score 0):

Differences: some, for example the legacy-libraries for Visual Basic. See [Hidden VB.Net-Features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102084/hidden-features-of-vb-net) and [Hidden C#.Net-Features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c) for a nice compilation of unique things.

Overlap: [Intermediate Language](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSIL). There you'll find all .Net-Features combined and the languages are at this point all equal.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not directly answering your question, but there are various VB.NET <> C# translators freely available. So if you come across some code in C# (say) and you need it in VB.NET you could get it translated.

A search for "vb.net c# translator" yielded the following as the first few hits.

http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/CodeTranslator/

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

http://authors.aspalliance.com/aldotnet/examples/translate.aspx

A word of warning, like all machine translations the results should be double checked. However, having said that they might do a "good enough" job to get you started and over the initial hurdle.

Answer (score 0):

C# vs. VB are very nearly semantically identical with fairly minor non-syntactic differences.  F#, Powershell, Ruby and Python are rather different.  F# is an interesting case: basically every C# feature maps to something in F# (sometimes in clever ways), but F# has its own features such as algebraic data types -- these do map to CLR constructs, but I'd class them as "semantic sugar" rather than "syntactic sugar"