# Mixed Encoding to String

Tags: vb.net, encoding, decoding

I have a string in VB.net that may contain something like the following:

> This is a 0x000020AC symbol

This is the UTF-32 encoding for the Euro Symbol according to this article http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/index.htm

I'd like to convert this into

> This is a € symbol

I've tried using UnicodeEncoding() class in VB.net (Framework 2.0, as I'm modifying a legacy application)

When I use this class to encode, and then decode I still get back the original string.

I expected that the UnicodeEncoding would recognise the already encoded part and not encode it against. But it appears to not be the case.

I'm a little lost now as to how I can convert a mixed encoded string into a normal string.

Background: When saving an Excel spreadsheet as CSV, anything outside of the ascii range gets converted to ?. So my idea is that if I can get my client to search/replace a few characters, such as the Euro symbol, into an encoded string such as 0x000020AC. Then I was hoping to convert those encoded parts back into the real symbols before I insert to a SQL database.

I've tried a function such as

```
Public Function Decode(ByVal s As String) As String
    Dim uni As New UnicodeEncoding()
    Dim encodedBytes As Byte() = uni.GetBytes(s)
    Dim output As String = ""

    output = uni.GetString(encodedBytes)

    Return output
End Function
```

Which was based on the examples on the MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.unicodeencoding.aspx

It could be that I have a complete mis-understanding of how this works in VB.net. In C# I can simply use escaped characters such as "\u20AC". But no such thing exists in VB.net.

Comment: I would use [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy(v=vs.80).aspx) to match `0x...` and use the custom match evaluator to convert the matched value back into a character.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to represent Unicode Chr Code in VB.Net String literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144053/how-to-represent-unicode-chr-code-in-vb-net-string-literal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on advice from Heinzi I implemented a Regex.Replace method using the following code, this appear to work for my examples.

```
Public Function Decode(ByVal s As String) As String
 Dim output As String = ""
 Dim sRegex As String = "0x[0-9a-zA-Z]{8}"

 Dim r As Regex = New Regex(sRegex)

 Dim myEvaluator As MatchEvaluator = New MatchEvaluator(AddressOf HexToString)

 output = r.Replace(s, myEvaluator)

 Return output
End Function

Public Function HexToString(ByVal hexString As Match) As String
 Dim uni As New UnicodeEncoding(True, True)
 Dim input As String = hexString.ToString
 input = input.Substring(2)
 input = input.TrimStart("0"c)

 Dim output As String

 Dim length As Integer = input.Length
 Dim upperBound As Integer = length \ 2
 If length Mod 2 = 0 Then
  upperBound -= 1
 Else
  input = "0" & input
 End If
 Dim bytes(upperBound) As Byte
 For i As Integer = 0 To upperBound
  bytes(i) = Convert.ToByte(input.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16)
 Next

 output = uni.GetString(bytes)

 Return output
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
Public Function Decode(Byval Coded as string) as string
     Return StrConv(Coded, vbUnicode)
End Function
```

Also, your function is invalid. It takes s as an argument, does a load of stuff and then outputs the s that was put into it instead of the stuff that was processed within it.

Comment: I saw that error in the question, sorry about that. I tried many versions of that script before the one posted. Anyway, unfortunately vbUnicode was dropped in .net and is for VB6 only. So that's not going to work for me.

Comment: What about System.Text.Encoding.Convert to convert the string as a byte array?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.convert(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I managed to find a way of doing it using Heinzi's comment earlier. Using Regex and a custom match evaluator, combined with a hextostring function. I'll post the code myself once I tidy it up a bit, to share it.