# what is typesafe in vb.net?

Tags: types

What is Type Safety? How does Type Safety affect us? Why is Type Safety Important? Writing Type-Safe Code. in what scenario we can achieve type safety?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102084/hidden-features-of-vb-net

Answer (score 0):

Type safety is checking for matched data types during compile time. For example int a ="John" returns error as variable 'a' is an integer and we are assigning a string value.  These data type mismatches are checked during compile time.