# Using Dynamic Column Names in a Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

```
foreach (Dimension dimensions in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Dimension)))
{
    var r = new ReferenceTable(dimensions).referenceItems;
    List<TVRawDataRecord> qry = TVRawDataList.Where(p => !r.Any(d => d.Value == p.BrandVariant))
                                             .ToList();                
    DimensionItem di = new DimensionItem(qry, dimensions);
    newDimensions.Add(di); 
 }
```

I am trying to create a Linq query that compares a list of `TVRawDataRecords` to those in an enum of `Dimensions` and where there is no match then add them to a new `DimensionIem` list. This all works fine but I need to substitute dynamically the `p.BrandVariant` in my `Where` statement with the dimensions enum value as the dimension value is the same as the `TVRawDataRecord` property name. This would mean I can have just these few lines of code to loop through 8 dimensions etc.

Can someone explain how I include the dimension in my Where statement? Thanks!

Comment: Why not substitute the property with the dimension value in your code? What happens when you do? What's not working?

Comment: The dimension value is the name of the field I'm after so I'm essentially trying to substitute p.BrandVariant with 'p + dimension' in each loop.

Comment: that just compiles. Did you check yourself? You mean `p.Dimension` coincides with `Dimension` enum? Thats not an issue at all? Did you try?

Comment: My issue is to replace p.BrandVariant dynamically on each foreach loop with the equivalent of 'p. + dimension' so the first pass will be p.BrandVariant, then p.Creative and so on - one for each enum. So I think the question is how I can update the Where statement dynamically.

Comment: So what is the linkage between p.Property and Dimension enum? Which enum value maps to which property of p? Or are they just one subsequent after the other etc?

Comment: You can regard Property and enum as the same name/value. There is 8 properties and 8 enums that map on the same name.

Comment: That's a bizarre design, really. Well let me think of something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost this is really a bizarre thing to do. You should think of an alternate design first. There are a couple coming to me now.

**Anyway you could use reflection to achieve what you are trying to achieve.**, well almost..

```
foreach (Dimension dimension in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Dimension)))
{
    var r = new ReferenceTable(dimension).referenceItems;
    var qry = TVRawDataList.Where(p => !r.Any(d => IsAMatch(p, dimension, d.Value)))
                           .ToList();     

    DimensionItem di = new DimensionItem(qry, dimension);
    newDimensions.Add(di); 
}

bool IsAMatch<T>(TVRawDataRecord obj, Dimension dimension, T valueToMatch)
{
    return valueToMatch == dimension.MapToTvRecordProperty<T>(obj);
}

T MapToTvRecordProperty<T>(this Dimension dimension, TVRawDataRecord obj)
{
    return obj.GetPropertyValue<T>(dimension.ToString());
}

T GetPropertyValue<T>(this TVRawDataRecord obj, string propertyName)
{
     var property = typeof(TVRawDataRecord).GetProperty(propertyName);
     if (property == null)
         return null; //or throw whatever

     return (T)property.GetValue(obj, null);
}
```

Strictly untested, uncompiled. But this should give an idea how it is done. You can make the `GetPropertyValue` function more generic, but that's a different thing. The `T` type argument in `Map` function (that maps a dimension enum to property of `TVRawDataRecord` class) is passed since you need to know the return type of the property.

**I would say a better alternate design is just to make a simple function that uses if else logic to return the right type**. So change `Map` function to this:

```
T MapToTvRecordProperty<T>(this Dimension dimension, TVRawDataRecord obj)
{
    switch (dimension)
    {
        case Dimension.BrandVariant:
            return obj.BrandVariant;
        case Dimension.Creative:
            return obj.Creative;

        .....

        default:
            throw;
    }
}
```

The advantage is that even if in future you change the name of any of the variables, your code wouldn't break (unlike the reflection approach). But the catch here is to choose the return type `T`. The second example wouldnt compile since return type doesnt match what is being returned. If all the properties are of the same type, then you can choose that type. If it's so really variable, then you will have to cast your property first to object and then to `T`, but still better than reflection!!

**An even better approach would be to specify attributes either [to property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2820676/661933) or [to enum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11008926/661933)**.

**And best of all if `BrandVariant` and `Creative` etc are classes of their own, you can make them all implement an interface which will have a property readonly `Dimension`** on them and you can access that property of your tv record properties to get the right dimension value!