# Keeping track of another application

Tags: .net, vb.net

How can I have my main application open a separate application and have it call an event in the main application when the separate application closes?

At the moment I am using:

```cs
Process.Start("notepad.exe", "C:\test.txt");
```

What I attempt to achieve is to get the main application to re-read the contents of test.txt once the separate application has saved and closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
Dim Process As Process = new Process()
Process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("notepad", "C:\test.txt")
Process.Start()
Process.WaitForExit()
// Do something
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want the main application to have to wait. I just want it to call an event once notepad closes.

Comment: What was the purpose of the @?

Comment: @Jimmay You noticed that before I rolled it back huh? Sorry about that! It's a C# thing, which I thought would be the same in VB. It isn't: [How to do a verbatim string literal in VB.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13155449)

Comment: If you don't want to block the program you can use the Process.Exited event rather than using threads.

Comment: Lol, good spot @Jimmay! (In case you hadn't already noticed, C# and VB are basically identical, ignoring these little differences)