# Error in using select * into statement in c#

Tags: c#

I am struggling to get my query to work in c# usng the select * into statement which will copy the data of the table and create a new table.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select  pp.upc as upc , pp.description as                     Description,sp.qty_onhand as Qty" +
                          "into TempProductProfile from product_profile pp" +
                          "inner join store_products sp on" +
                          "pp.upc = sp.upc" +
                          "order by pp.description", con))

                   cmd.executenonquery(): <-- got error here         
        }
```

Can anyone point me the right way?.
thanks

Comment: Next time create a verbatim string for your sql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13155449/how-to-do-a-verbatim-string-literal-in-vb-net

Comment: thanks grant for pointing it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select  pp.upc as upc , pp.description as                     Description,sp.qty_onhand as Qty
                          into TempProductProfile from product_profile pp
                          inner join store_products sp on
                          pp.upc = sp.upc
                          order by pp.description", con))

                   cmd.executenonquery(): <-- got error here         
        }
```

Write the query like this.With `@` you can write string on more than one line ! The problem is explain in `Grant Winney` answer about wrong concatenation of strings.

Comment: An actual solution. +1

Comment: @Androidz you are welcome ! Good luck with the project.

Answer (score 3):

Your query, as it is now, is going to look something like:

> ... sp.qty_onhand as Qtyinto TempProductProfile from product_profile ppinner join ...

You need to insert a space at the beginning of each line you're concatenating:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "select  pp.upc as upc , pp.description as Description,sp.qty_onhand as Qty" +
    " into TempProductProfile from product_profile pp" +
    " inner join store_products sp on" +
    " pp.upc = sp.upc" +
    " order by pp.description", con))
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a space at the start of each line of text, excluding the first one.

As you don't have any spaces between your lines of text, your SQL is

```
select  pp.upc as upc , pp.description as Description,sp.qty_onhand as Qtyinto TempProductProfile from product_profile ppinner join store_products sp onpp.upc = sp.upcorder by pp.description
```