# Best practice for structuring/grouping a collection of string constant in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop

I would like a wau to organize and group a collection of strings in the same way as an enum. That is with a name used in code and a value. Since enums can only be created as integrals, I usually do like this:

```
**Public Structure SomeStrings
    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Something1 As String
        Get
              Return "Something1"            
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Something2 As Color
        Get
            Return "Something2"
        End Get
    End Property
End Structure**
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Can't you just use the `ToString()` of an enum?

Comment: VB.NET also has `Consts` and you can use static readonly *fields* (instead of properties) for this as well.

Comment: Have you considered using [String Resource files](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/netres090117.htm)?

Comment: @millimoose: ToString doesn't allow e.g. spaces

Comment: @millimoose: can you group consts in any way? e.g. use in code like this: SomeStrings.Something1

Comment: @DaveShaw: I know the resource files, but can you group a collection there?

Comment: @SuppaiKamo In VB.NET, you'd make `SomeStrings` a [module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aaxss7da.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there a better way?

Yes, use `Shared ReadOnly` fields instead of properties. You can even get proper IDE auto-completion like for real enums by using an undocumented XML doc tag:

```
''' <completionlist cref="SomeStrings"/>
Public Structure SomeStrings
    Public Shared ReadOnly Something1 As String = "Something1"
    ' etc.
End Structure
```

For more details, [refer to my previous answer explaining this feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/102217/1968).

Comment: Can you group the strings like this? e.g. use in code like this: SomeStrings.Something1? Or is it simply keeping the Public Shared ReadOnly statements in a structure like in my approach?

Comment: I never knew about `<completionlist>`. This is a total game changer!

Comment: @Konrad: my bad, didn't see the "Structure" in your code, works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into creating [resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wkcc526%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

An other option could be to use a dictionary.

```
Dim d As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)

d.Add(1, "String 1")
d.Add(2, "String 2")

Console.WriteLine(d(2))
```