# VBNet Date Compare

Tags: vb.net, date, compare

Currently, i have this code.

```
Dim iCurrentDate As Date = Now
Dim iStartDate As Date = CDate(dtFrom.Text)
Dim iEndDate As Date = CDate(dtTo.Text)

If (iCurrentDate > iStartDate) And (iCurrentDate < iEndDate) Then
    Console.WriteLine("Current date is within the range.")
    'Other Codes here
Else
    Console.WriteLine("Current date is in the range.")
    'Other Codes here
End If
```

OR

```
Dim iObj As Object = IIf((iCurrentDate > iStartDate) And (iCurrentDate < iEndDate), "Current date is within the range.", "Current date is in the range.")
Console.WriteLine(iObj.ToString)
'Other Codes here
```

Is there any substitute in the above code? Just like `BETWEEN` in sql queries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing built-in, but you could have an extension method:

```
<Extension()> _
Public Function IsBetween(theDate As DateTime, minDate As DateTime, maxDate As DateTime) As Boolean
    Return theDate > minDate AndAlso theDate < maxDate
End Function
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
If iCurrentDate.IsBetween(iStartDate, iEndDate) Then
    Console.WriteLine("Current date is within the range.")
    'Other Codes here
Else
    Console.WriteLine("Current date is not in the range.")
    'Other Codes here
End If
```

Or like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(If(iCurrentDate.IsBetween(iStartDate, iEndDate), _
                     "Current date is within the range.", _
                     "Current date is not in the range."))
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no BETWEEN operator in .NET, are you really missing it?

**Note**:

You could/should [use IF instead of IIF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2008/03/11/if-operator-a-new-and-improved-iif-sophia-salim.aspx).

```
Dim message = _
    If((iCurrentDate > iStartDate) AndAlso (iCurrentDate < iEndDate), _
    "Current date is within the range.", _
    "Current date is not in the range.")
```

- It's faster: second part will only be evaluated if first is `false`, no boxing/unboxing
- It's safer: no NullRefernceException because you've forgotten above
- It's more readable and  type-safe

Comment: sir, mind if i ask this question? What is the difference between AND and ANDALSO?

Comment: the question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302047/what-is-the-difference-between-and-and-andalso-in-vb-net. anyway thank you still.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct substitute I have seen something this with a select case though:

```
Select Case iCurrentDate
    Case iStartDate To iEndDate
        'is between
    Case Else
        'is not
End Select
```

I have never used anything like that though.  I am not sure what its origin is.  I generally go with a slight modification to your code, using AndAlso:

```
   If (iCurrentDate > iStartDate) AndAlso (iCurrentDate < iEndDate) Then
            Console.WriteLine("Current date is within the range.")
            'Other Codes here
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Current date is in the range.")
            'Other Codes here
        End If
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know you could compare dates in a Select Case like this. One thing to be aware of is that it problably includes both iStartDate and iEndDate, so it's the equivalent of: `If iCurrentDate >= iStartDate AndAlso iCurrentDate <= iEndDate`

Comment: Yeah, I never tested it.  I am not sure if using it is good or bad practice I have never been able to find any documentation on it.

Comment: I suppose it's not a bad practice, but it's use is limited because you can't exclude the start and/or end dates from the range. Typically in my date comparisons, I would include the start date, but exclude the end date, so I wouldn't be able to use a Select Case directly.