# vb.net combine and or operators

Tags: vb.net

very simple question, how to combine and or operators into the same statement.

c.GetType is getType(TextBox) AND foo or bar or baz

this is not working

```
For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
    If (c.GetType Is GetType(TextBox)) And ((c.Name <> "txtID") Or (c.Name <> "txtAltEmail")) Then
        'do something
    End If
Next
```

this works:

```
For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
    If (c.GetType Is GetType(TextBox)) And (c.Name <> "txtID") Then
        'do something
    End If
Next
```

thanks, I'm a .net newbie!

Comment: What error are you getting? the first statment looks fine to me

Comment: @LuisSánchez: The first statement is equivalent to `If (c.GetType Is GetType(TextBox)) And True Then`.

Comment: @Heinzi Indeed, for a moment there I was seeing and `=` instead of a `<>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the way, you can use LINQ which improves the intelligibility.:

```
Dim allTextBoxes = From txt In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
                  Where txt.Name <> "txtID" AndAlso txt.Name <> "txtAltEmail"
For Each txt In allTextBoxes
    ' do something with the TextBox '
Next
```

- `OfType` returns only the controls of the given type, in this case TextBoxes
- `Where` filters the controls by the `Name` property (note: [`And` and `AndAlso` difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302047/what-is-the-difference-between-and-and-andalso-in-vb-net))
- the `For Each` iterates the resulting `IEnumerable(Of TextBox)`

Answer (score 1):

Your first statement does not make sense from a mathematical point of view. The expression

```
X <> A or X <> B
```

will always return `true` (given that `A <> B`, which is satisfied in your case since `"txtID" <> "txtAltEmail"`).

(If `X = A`, the second clause will be true. If `X = B`, the first clause will be true. If `X` is anything else, both clauses will be true.)

What you probably meant to write was

```
If (TypeOf c Is TextBox) AndAlso (c.Name <> "txtID") AndAlso (c.Name <> "txtAltEmail") Then
```

or

```
If (TypeOf c Is TextBox) AndAlso Not ((c.Name = "txtID") OrElse (c.Name = "txtAltEmail")) Then
```

which is logically equivalent.

(I've also taken the liberty to change your type check to a more elegant variant and replace And/Or with their more efficient counterparts.)

Comment: @LuisSánchez: Thanks. I've decided to remove the `)` instead.