# conditions are met, but the code under if statement doesn't execute

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I'm trying to check the following conditions in my if statement.
However even when the conditions are met, the code under the if statement doesn't execute.

```
If (Gnum(0, 0) = Rnum(0, 0) & Gnum(0, 1) = Rnum(0, 1) & Gnum(0, 2) = Rnum(0, 2)) Then
    Lbl_Msg.Text = "Send Msg"
End If
```

Comment: I am NOT VB specialist, just a general note:
Check the operators usage `=`, `&` and their precedence.  
As far as I can see it: `Gnum(0, 0) = Rnum(0, 0) & Gnum(0, 1) = Rnum(0, 1)` is evaluated as `Gnum(0, 0) = ( Rnum(0, 0) & Gnum(0, 1) ) = Rnum(0, 1)` I.e. the middle `&` gets evaluated first

Comment: @GermannArlington: Don't you mean "&" operator? I don't think there's a problem with the use of "=" here ;-)

Comment: @Meta-Knight Yes, I only just noticed that `&` is not a logical operator at all in VB...

Comment: Note: that switching Option Strict On will alert you that something is wrong here (i.e. Your code won't compile)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not certain if '&' will work as intended here as '&' is for concatenation in vb.net

Try using 'and' instead.

Edit: what vb.net thinks you're trying to do here is concatenating all those variables and checking whether or not that result is equal to true (which it is not going to be). That's why the code inside the if statement is not being executed but also no error is being shown.

Comment: WoW, that was the problem. THANKS DUDE

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you want to do `AND` checks. Instead of `&`, try using `AndAlso`

```
If (Gnum(0, 0) = Rnum(0, 0) AndAlso Gnum(0, 1) = Rnum(0, 1) AndAlso Gnum(0, 2) = Rnum(0, 2)) Then
    Lbl_Msg.Text = "Send Msg"
end if
```

`&` is used to concatenate strings in VB.NET.

Comment: yes I want to do AND checks, whats the diff between "and"  and "andalso"?

Comment: `And` evaluates both sides, whereas `AndAlso` only evaluates the right hand side if the left hand side is true. Therefore, `AndAlso` should be faster (although real-life performance may not be noticeable depending on what you're doing). If you're familiar with C#, `AndAlso` is the equivalent of `&&`. Bit more info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302047/what-is-the-difference-between-and-and-andalso-in-vb-net

Comment: >> although real-life performance may not be noticeable depending on what you're doing <<  
It makes a difference, if the right side is considerably more "expensive" than the left side. Like `If x=0 AndAlso ExpensiveFunction(y) < 3`, and/or if the left side evaluates to `true` very rarely

Answer (score 0):

```
If (Gnum(0, 0) = Rnum(0, 0) AND Gnum(0, 1) = Rnum(0, 1) AND Gnum(0, 2) = Rnum(0, 2)) Then
    Lbl_Msg.Text = "Send Msg"
Else
    Lbl_Msg.Text = "see if this text is written to confirm if your if is true"
End If
```

Comment: This doesn't give anything more than the two answers already provided