# If...Else... Statement Issue

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code:

```
Dim UserID As String = "James"
Dim AccNo As String = "S10001"
Dim err As Boolean = False

If Left(AccNo , 1) = "S" Then
    If UserID <> "Alex" Or UserID <> "James" Then
         err = True
    End If
End If
```

Why I always get the result err=True? Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: That's the right result. If you change the OR into AND, you'll get err = False

Comment: `A <> B Or A <> C` is True when `B <> C`. And obviously `"Alex" <> "James"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you maybe wanted `And` rather than `Or`, because trivially, a `UserID` will always not be equal to at least one of two distinctly different values, and so one or other of the comparisons will always be true:

```
If Left(AccNo , 1) = "S" Then
    If UserID <> "Alex" And UserID <> "James" Then
         err = True
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are doing two 'not' or 'other than' statements which must always be true, because whatever value you test the other is always true.

Answer (score 0):

Because while UserID is equal to 'James' it is also not equals to 'Alex' hence the condition satisfies and changes the variable to true.

Answer (score 0):

That's the right result.

1st condition: `Left(AccNo , 1) = "S"` is true, so it enters the if block

2nd condition: `(UserID <> "Alex" Or UserID <> "James")` -> If either of the two result is true,  you code will execute the If block.
If you don't want to enter the condition, just change the `OR` into `AND`, meaning that the User should **NOT** be *James* **NOR** should he be *Alex*

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to express something like "The user id is neither Alex nor James". This in logic would be `not (UserID is Alex or UserId is James)`. As `not (x or y)` is the same as `not x and not y`, this equals `UserID is not Alex and UserId is not James`, or in VB syntax:

```
UserID <> "Alex" And UserID <> "James"
```

Answer (score 0):

As a sidenote, you can make your code look a bit nicer, if you use something like this:

```
If Not {"A", "B", "C"}.Contains("D") Then
        ' do something
    End If
```

This replaces

```
If "D" <> "A" AndAlso "D" <> "B" AndAlso "D" <> "C" Then
        ' do something
    End If
```

Also - as you might have noticed - VB also knows "AndAlso" and "OrElse" which should in most situations used to replace "And" and "Or". Check this for an explanation: [AndAlso vs And](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302047/what-is-the-difference-between-and-and-andalso-in-vb-net)