# VB - Index outside of bounds?

Tags: vb.net, indexoutofboundsexception

Oh my god i hate this thing, i tried millions of ways but couldn't find a working one. Let me explain:

I'm testing each line and checking the first word to be "copy" alright ? After the word copy i want to see if the next word is "1" , the third is "<" and the last is ">" , if all these conditions are fullfilled then the text between "<" and ">" needs to be stored in the variable "copy1" (even if there is more than 1 word between them).

What my code is:

```
For i = 0 To lstCode.Items.Count - 1

Dim str As String = lstCode.Items.Item(i)

Dim strA() As String = Split(str)

Dim copy1 as string

Dim copy2 as string

Select Case strA(0)


Case copy


If strA(1) = "1" And strA(2) = "<" And strA(strA.Count - 1) = ">" Then

copy1 = ""

For lr As Integer = 3 To strA.Count - 2

copy1 &= (strA(lr) & " ")

Next

End if

End select
```

And, when i debug it i get the error: Index was outside the bounds of the array ... Does anybody have any idea ?

---

There is something important i forgot to add, this is the whole code:

```
 Case "copy"

                    If strA(1) = "1" And strA(2) = "<" And strA(strA.Count - 1) = ">" Then
                        copy1 = ""

                        For lr As Integer = 3 To strA.Count - 2
                            copy1 &= (strA(lr) & " ")
                        Next


                    ElseIf strA(1) = "2" And strA(2) = "<" And strA(strA.Count - 1) = ">" Then
                        copy2 = ""

                        For lrs As Integer = 3 To strA.Count - 2
                            copy2 &= (strA(lrs) & " ")
                        Next



                    ElseIf strA(1) = "run" Then
                        Try
                            IO.File.Copy(copy1, copy2)
                        Catch ex As IO.IOException
                        End Try
                    End If


            End Select
```

So everything works like a charm: copy 1 < c:\csb.log > , copy 2 < c:\blabla.txt > but when the " copy run " statement comes in it gives me the error...

Comment: I forgot to say that i'm using Visual Basic 2010. Sorry.

Comment: in which line you got that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the operator [And with AndAlso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302047/what-is-the-difference-between-and-and-andalso-in-vb-net).

The second one applies [Short Circuit Evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) to your expression, meaning if the first expression is false the second, third and so on expressions on the same line are not evaluated.

In your line

```
 If strA(1) = "1" And strA(2)  = "<" And .......
```

when the value is "Run" you still evaluate the expression `strA(2) = "<"` but there is no element at index 2 so you get the error.