# If condition in LINQ count clause using expression method

Tags: vb.net, linq

My data looks like:

```
A    | B
80   | 80
90   | 10
80   | NULL
```

I count all non Null values of B with

```
.C = eGroup.Count(Function(x) x.IsBNull = False)
```

But I need another condition in my expression since I just want to count if A >= B.

I tried

```
.C = eGroup.Count(Function(x) x.IsBNull = False And x.A >= x.B)
```

but I get an error as soon as the B is NULL.

EDIT:
I get my data from a dataset
I have a field "Teams" and group my dataset by teams befor I use the query above:

dim query = From row in _dataset.DS
Group row by row.Team Into eGroup = Group

Comment: What's `eGroup`, what's `IsBNull`(a typo?)?

Comment: It is just a typo or do you really have that close parenthesys in that place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `AndAlso` instead of `And`, the latter always evaluates also the second condition even if the first was already `False`.  Read: [What is the difference between And and AndAlso in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302047/what-is-the-difference-between-and-and-andalso-in-vb-net)

```
.C = eGroup.Count(Function(x) x.IsBNull = False AndAlso x.A >= x.B)
```

As an aside, the same applies to `Or` and `OrElse`. I've hardly ever used `And` or `Or` in 12 years of VB.NET development.

Comment: Thanks this works great! And you also gave a great advide using OrElse and AndAlso. Thanks for that too!!!