# InvalidCastException Specified cast is not valid

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, label, picturebox

I wan't to make a PictureBox and a Label show if TextBox1 and TextBox2 Texts equal definite word.

But I receive an error...
Please, help

Here is the code:

```
Public Class Appearance
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = "Brown" & TextBox2.Text = "Brown" Then
            PictureBox4.Image = My.Resources.brown
            PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.blue
            PictureBox5.Image = My.Resources.green
            PictureBox4.Visible = True
            PictureBox2.Visible = True
            PictureBox5.Visible = True
            Label7.Visible = True
            Label8.Visible = True
            Label9.Visible = True
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please don't forget to Accept [Neolisk's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26692810/2410892) answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> #### Edit : Sorry, missed you wanted to compare both TextBox1 and TextBox2 values to one String Value

Right evaluation is already provided by [Neolisk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26692810/2410892) :

```
    If TextBox1.Text = "Brown" AndAlso TextBox2.Text = "Brown" Then
```

---

> #### EDIT : the following suggestion is wrong..

Replace this

```
    If TextBox1.Text = "Brown" & TextBox2.Text = "Brown" Then
```

by this :

```
    If TextBox1.Text = TextBox2.Text Then
```

---

> #### EDIT : I leave the explanation here

If you write `If TextBox1.Text = "Brown" & TextBox2.Text = "Brown" Then`, and we suppose that TextBox2.Text ***is*** *"Brown"* what's happening is :

- Since the `&` is for String concatenation in VB, just like `+`, `TextBox1.Text` will be compared to the chain `"Brown" & TextBox2.Text = "Brown"`.
- With `"Brown" & TextBox2.Text = "Brown"`, `"Brown" & TextBox2.Text` will be evaluated first, since the `&` string concatener takes precedence over the `=` boolean evaluation. You'll get the concatenated string `"BrownBrown"` (= "Brown").
- But then, you'll have `"BrownBrown" = "Brown"`, and at this stage, the full chain of evaluation is `If TextBox1.Text = "BrownBrown" = "Brown" Then`.
- `TextBox1.Text = "BrownBrown"` will be evaluated first and will return `False`. In the end, you're evaluating :

---

```
    If False = "Brown" Then ' <- Boolean comparison with String Error !
```

---

Since you're new to VB, good to know :

Note that `AndAlso` has the shorcut feature. If the evaluation on the left part is False, the right part **is not** evaluated.

To evaluate both left and right, there is the `And` comparer. But, honestly, comparing

```
    If False = True And "SameValue" = "SameValue" ' will always return False.
```

There is NO meaning in comparing the right side if the left is already `False`. You ought to know that this is a **unique** glitch of VB. ***However, I don't know if it was fixed since***. But if not, the same applies for `Or` and `OrElse`.

=> You'd better use `AndAlso` and `OrElse` instead of `And/Or` *from the start*.

Answer (score 1):

In VB.NET `&` means [string concatenation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfx50zyk.aspx). You probably want to use [`AndAlso`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302047/what-is-the-difference-between-and-and-andalso-in-vb-net):

```
If TextBox1.Text = "Brown" AndAlso TextBox2.Text = "Brown" Then
```

Comment: Yes, I'm new to  VB.net and havent't known what to use, thanks a lot!