# Visual Basic: How to check if three PictureBox have same image?

Tags: vb.net

I know how to check if two PictureBox have same Image and it works:

```
If PictureBox1.Image Is PictureBox2.Image Then   
**What I want it to do**
End If
```

I tried do it with three PictureBox but not working:

```
If (PictureBox1.Image Is PictureBox2.Image) And (PictureBox1.Image Is PictureBox3.Image) Then
MessageBox.Show("TEST")
End If
```

If someone could help me, I would be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: That depends on how you load the image. If you use the `PictureBox.ImageLocation` property you can just verify that... But if you dynamically load images you have to compare them pixel by pixel.

Comment: Okey. I used PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("*source here*")

But how to compare if I use PictureBox.ImageLocation? Sry for stupid question. I'm new with Visual Basic.

Comment: Use `PictureBox1.ImageLocation = "source here"`, then just compare the `ImageLocation` properties. `If PictureBox1.ImageLocation = PictureBox2.ImageLocation Then` --- This will only work if you always use the `ImageLocation` property,

Comment: Thank you so much! :) Now it works: If (PictureBox1.ImageLocation = PictureBox2.ImageLocation) And (PictureBox1.ImageLocation = PictureBox3.ImageLocation) Then

Comment: No problem! But you should use `AndAlso` instead of `And`. It's faster.

Comment: http://www.panopticoncentral.net/2003/08/18/the-ballad-of-andalso-and-orelse/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302047/what-is-the-difference-between-and-and-andalso-in-vb-net

Comment: ..Because AndAlso doesn't evaluate your second expression if the first one is false.

Comment: @Kake_Fisk : Yep. Was in a hurry while writing so I didn't have the time to include an explanation. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that in VB.net, you need to do something like:

```
If picturebox1.Image Is picturebox2.Image And picturebox1.Image Is picturebox3.Image Then
  '**What you want to do**
End if
```

Comment: You should probably test this.