# Shorten my ElseIf Statement. How?

Tags: vb.net

I have something here that I want to know, I hope everyone can help me with this. So here's my question, how can I shorten this code of mine. :)

```
If MetroTextBox1.Text = "" Then
            If MetroCheckBox1.Checked = True And MetroCheckBox2.Checked = False Then
                query = "select id, fname, mname, lname, dept, salary, ' ' as lengthservice from tbl_Employee where dresigned is null and " +
                        " (id like '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%' or fname like '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%' or mname like '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%' or lname like '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%' or dept like '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%') "
                dt = c.GetDataTable(query)
            ElseIf MetroCheckBox2.Checked = True And MetroCheckBox1.Checked = False Then
                query = "select id, fname, mname, lname, dept, salary, ' ' as lengthservice from tbl_Employee where dresigned is not null and " +
                        " (id like '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%' or fname like '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%' or mname like '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%' or lname like '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%' or dept like '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%') "
                dt = c.GetDataTable(query)
            ElseIf MetroCheckBox1.Checked = True And MetroCheckBox2.Checked = True Then
                query = "select id, fname, mname, lname, dept, salary from tbl_Employee" +
                        " where id like '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%' or fname like '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%' or mname like '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%' or lname like '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%' or dept like '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%' "
                dt = c.GetDataTable(query)
            End If
        ElseIf MetroTextBox1.Text <> "" Then
            If MetroCheckBox1.Checked = True And MetroCheckBox2.Checked = False Then
                query = "select id, fname, mname, lname, dept, salary, ' ' as lengthservice from tbl_Employee where dresigned is null and " +
                        " (id like '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%' or fname like '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%' or mname like '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%' or lname like '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%' or dept like '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%') "
                dt = c.GetDataTable(query)
            ElseIf MetroCheckBox2.Checked = True And MetroCheckBox1.Checked = False Then
                query = "select id, fname, mname, lname, dept, salary, ' ' as lengthservice from tbl_Employee where dresigned is not null and " +
                        " (id like '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%' or fname like '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%' or mname like '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%' or lname like '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%' or dept like '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%') "
                dt = c.GetDataTable(query)
            ElseIf MetroCheckBox1.Checked = True And MetroCheckBox2.Checked = True Then
                query = "select id, fname, mname, lname, dept, salary from tbl_Employee" +
                        " where id like '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%' or fname like '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%' or mname like '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%' or lname like '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%' or dept like '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%' "
                dt = c.GetDataTable(query)
            End If
        Else
            query = "select id, fname, mname, lname, dept, salary, ' ' as lengthservice from tbl_Employee where id = ''"
            dt = c.GetDataTable(query)
        End If
```

Comment: your code seems messy! i saw in the first `if`, you have: `If MetroTextBox1.Text = "" Then` but later in related code block, you use its value: `If MetroCheckBox1.Checked = True And MetroCheckBox2.Checked = False Then query = "select id, fname, ... " +
      " (id like '%" & **MetroTextBox1.Text** & ...` which dose not seems to be correct!

Comment: What is `c` in your code above? I was trying to write a parameterised version to avoid the vulnerability to SQL injection caused by passing the `MetroTextBox1.Text` in without any validation

Comment: You should use `AndAlso`/`OrElse` instead of `And`/`Or`. [Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/302047/4934172).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the question is about shortening the code, here's how:

```
query = " (id like '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%' or fname like '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%' or mname like '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%' or lname like '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%' or dept like '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%')"
If MetroTextBox1.Text = "" Then
    If MetroCheckBox1.Checked = True And MetroCheckBox2.Checked = False Then
        query = "select id, fname, mname, lname, dept, salary, ' ' as lengthservice from tbl_Employee where dresigned is null and" + query
    ElseIf MetroCheckBox2.Checked = True And MetroCheckBox1.Checked = False Then
        query = "select id, fname, mname, lname, dept, salary, ' ' as lengthservice from tbl_Employee where dresigned is not null and" + query
    ElseIf MetroCheckBox1.Checked = True And MetroCheckBox2.Checked = True Then
        query = "select id, fname, mname, lname, dept, salary from tbl_Employee where" + query
    End If
ElseIf MetroTextBox1.Text <> "" Then
    If MetroCheckBox1.Checked = True And MetroCheckBox2.Checked = False Then
        query = "select id, fname, mname, lname, dept, salary, ' ' as lengthservice from tbl_Employee where dresigned is null and" + query
    ElseIf MetroCheckBox2.Checked = True And MetroCheckBox1.Checked = False Then
        query = "select id, fname, mname, lname, dept, salary, ' ' as lengthservice from tbl_Employee where dresigned is not null and" + query
    ElseIf MetroCheckBox1.Checked = True And MetroCheckBox2.Checked = True Then
        query = "select id, fname, mname, lname, dept, salary from tbl_Employee where" + query
    End If
Else
    query = "select id, fname, mname, lname, dept, salary, ' ' as lengthservice from tbl_Employee where id = ''"
End If
dt = c.GetDataTable(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is better (and shorter) code:

```
Dim t1 As String = MetroTextBox1.Text
Dim c1 As Boolean = MetroCheckBox1.Checked
Dim c2 As Boolean = MetroCheckBox2.Checked

Dim a, b As String
a = "select id, fname, mname, lname, dept, salary"
b = "(id like '%" & t1 & "%' or fname like '%" & t1 & "%' or mname like '%" & t1 & "%' or lname like '%" & t1 & "%' or dept like '%" & t1 & "%') "

If c1 And Not c2 Then
    query = a + ", ' ' as lengthservice from tbl_Employee where dresigned is null and " + b

ElseIf c2 And Not c1 Then
    query = a + ", ' ' as lengthservice from tbl_Employee where dresigned is not null and " + b

Else 'If c1 And c2 Then
    query = a + " from tbl_Employee where " + b

End If

dt = c.GetDataTable(query)
```

(it is obvious that the final `Else` is never called because always one of MetroTextBox1.Text = "" or MetroTextBox1.Text <> "" will be true).

But, there is a note here. When MetroTextBox1.Text = "", the condition specified in b becomes `(id like '%%' or fname like '%%' or ...)`, something like `where 1=1` which can be removed from the query. but it is not based on your original code. if you like, i could give the modified code

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is about shortening the code, here is short solution without `If` statement

```
Dim query As String = 
    "SELECT id, fname, mname, lname, dept, salary, ' ' AS lengthservice
     FROM tbl_Employee
     WHERE (id LIKE @MetroTextBox1 
         OR fname LIKE '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%'
         OR mname LIKE '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%' 
         OR lname LIKE '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%' 
         OR dept LIKE '%" & MetroTextBox1.Text & "%')"

Dim condition As New Dictionary(Of Byte, String) From
{
    {0, ""}, 'You don't have result for case False, False
    {1, " AND dresigned IS NULL"}, 'If MetroCheckBox1.Checked = True
    {2, " AND dresigned IS NOT NULL"}, 'If MetroCheckBox2.Checked = True
    {3, ""}  'Both Checkboxes are checked
}

Dim checkBox1 As Byte = Convert.ToByte(MetroCheckBox1)
Dim checkBox2 As Byte = Convert.ToByte(MetroCheckBox2) << 1
Dim selection As Byte = checkBox1 Or checkBox2

query = query & condition(selection)

dt = c.GetDataTable(query)
```

And very important: **Use SqlParameters for passing values to the query**

Parameters will save you from Sql injection problems and also will make your queries run little bid faster.