# In Visual Studio: Make value of one Textbox result to a value in another Textbox1

Tags: vb.net

Am building a VB project. I have two textboxes:

```
Textbox1
Textbox2
```

I want, if the value of `textbox1` equals to numbers between 10-20, the  `textbox2` to automatically display the word "Thanks".

I thought the code will be something like this:

```
If Textbox1.text = integer("10-20") then
Textbox2.text = "Thanks"
End if
```

But its not working. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Thanks for the edit and the answer..... The question is solved now. Your code works perfect.  Thanks @YowE3K

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If YowE3K's answer worked you should mark it as accepted by pressing the check mark on the post. Please have a look at the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for a little introduction to how this site works.

Comment: Also, you can write the comment directly on his answer instead of on your question.

Comment: @VisualVincent - Just FYI - I originally had my answer as a comment, so the "thanks" was posted before I wrote the actual "answer".  (And that's probably why I won't get an "accepted answer" tick too.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that `Textbox1` contains numbers, but you are just wanting to test whether the values are between 10 and 20, you could do

```
If CInt(Textbox1.Text) >= 10 AndAlso CInt(Textbox1.Text) <= 20 Then
    Textbox2.Text = "Thanks"
End If
```

If you first need to check for the presence of numbers, rather than garbage, it gets a little bit messier.

Comment: I recommend you use [**`AndAlso`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb8x3kfz.aspx) instead of `And` since the former is [**short-circuited**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/302067/3740093). Other than that, this is a nice answer!

Comment: @VisualVincent - Thanks - I've been using VBA for so long now (my employer thinks Visual Studio is a security risk !?!?) that I had forgotten that `AndAlso` and `OrElse` even existed.

Comment: Haha, what?! VBA is a bigger security risk than VS. ;)

Comment: @VisualVincent - Supposedly I could hack into all the other company systems using VS.  (They don't seem to realise that, if I wanted to, I could simply write .Net code using Notepad, and then compile it, with the only downside being no IDE.)

Comment: They'll never fully understand how capable a dedicated/passionate programmer can be... **--** Speaking of hacking: I found a flaw in my college's system which allowed me to gain access to every computer on the network. I could literally do anything I wanted with them, so for testing purposes I wrote a trojan which I silently installed on some of the computers. It was easy to remove and pretty harmless (unless the wrong person gets access to it). **--** I notified the IT department about the flaw and it has since been fixed.