# Why And operator in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I always use `AndAlso` while checking multiple conditions as it doesn't evaluate right side unless left one is true. I don't see any situation where someone would like to evaluate right side even if left one fails. If it was needed then why they didn't include same in `C#`.

**Update:**

As accepted answer pointed out that it exists because it is used for bitwise operation, that fine enough but I still think they would have overloaded `And` operator to serve both purposes and just not created `AndAlso`. If anyone can pour some light on it, this question is still open :)

Comment: They included the same in c#. In c# you can use `&` (And) or `&&` (AndAlso)

Comment: c# does have the same. & = And, && = AndAlso.

Comment: @Pikoh thanks, never knew that :)

Comment: see a good answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302047/what-is-the-difference-between-and-and-andalso-in-vb-net)

Comment: From Paul Vick, MSFT, who partook in the decision to introduce AndAlso: [The Ballad of AndAlso and OrElse](http://www.panopticoncentral.net/2003/08/18/the-ballad-of-andalso-and-orelse/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They included the same in `C#`. In `C#` you can use `&` (And) or `&&` (AndAlso).

There's no real use case i can imagine for the not short-circuit operator when comparing **booleans**, but `And` can be used with numeric values, and it then does a bitwise comparison. That's why it exists. But when comparing boolean types, you'll always be using the short-circuit version.

Answer (score 0):

And is also a bit operator. Here is an example showing a mix of And an AndAlso.

```
    Dim foo? As Integer = 5

    If foo.HasValue AndAlso (foo And 1) = 1 AndAlso (foo And 4) = 4 Then
        Stop
    End If
```