# Vb.net - Datatable receiving index out of range exception even though index exists

Tags: vb.net, datatable

Sometimes, my application throws random index out of range exceptions, and I'm a bit lost to what the reason is..

Here's a screenshot: 
[image]

As you can see the index (thi3) is under the rows count, so I don't see the problem??

Edit: This is where I declare the columns for the datatable (happens on form load)

```
InternalDataTable.Columns.Add("Domain")
InternalDataTable.Columns.Add("Anchor text")
InternalDataTable.Columns.Add("Status")
InternalDataTable.Columns.Add("E. Links")
InternalDataTable.Columns.Add("Thread #")
InternalDataTable.Columns.Add("Tjek", GetType(Boolean))

DataGridView1.DataSource = InternalDataTable
```

Edit2: I now received an error again, but now at the line below the highlighted line in the image, so indeed the problem is something with the item(x)

`If InternalDataTable.Rows(thi3).Item(2) = "" Then`

Edit3: Once again, the error occured, see screenshot here https://i.gyazo.com/a7cc582e4cbf33bea59a8efb9bb36497.png - (cant embed images yet) I know i should post code, but this image gives a view that both columns and rows & items are within index.

Comment: Change your [And with AndAlso](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302047/what-is-the-difference-between-and-and-andalso-in-vb-net), Next time do not post images of code. Post directly the code

Comment: Roger that. Thanks, I will give that a shot.

Comment: As @Steve says, you should use `AndAlso` to prevent the second expression being evaluated when `thi3` is too large. However, from your screenshot, that doesn't seem to be the problem here. In that case, the problem could be that `InternalDataTable.Rows(thi3)` has less than one `Item`.

Comment: @Blackwood - Yes, but see the latest screenshot though. Both  rows and columns are within the index.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you may have inserted several `rows`, but you don't have any `Columns`

```
InternalDataTable.Rows(thi3).Item(0) = ""
```

The `.Item(0)` can be causing theindex out of range exception.

Also, I recommend you changing the whole if to this one:

```
if thi3 < InternalDataTable.Rows.Count andalso InternalDataTable.Columns.Count > 2  andalso InternalDataTable.rows(Thi3).Item(0) <> "" then
```

Attention to change the `<=` to `<` since accessing the Rowcount index will also generate the index out of range exception.

Comment: I do have the columns added, posted code of where I add them. But yeah, that have crossed my mind as well. I'm running my application again, waiting to see if it will throw any exceptions this time..