# Custom Property is not a member of Control [vb.net]

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I am fairly new to vb.net and am wondering if I am doing any of this right.

In my program, I created a custom control (`CustomControl`), which and has a custom property (`CustomProperty`).

Within the program, I have a For Each statement that checks each `CustomControl` within a form and changes the value of `CustomProperty` if certain criteria is met:

```
For Each _CustomControl as Control in Controls
    If TypeOf _CustomControl is CustomControl and [criteria met]
        _CustomControl.CustomProperty = value
    End If
next
```

Whenever I type in the third line, it gives me the following message:

> 'CustomProperty' is not a member of 'Control'.

I understand that my custom property does not typically belong to 'Controls', and I was wondering if there is something that I should add to the code or if I should type it in some other way.

I appreciate any help that you can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer given is fine, but a better way is to filter out the unneeded controls beforehand using `OfType`. This makes the type check unnecessary.

```
For Each _CustomControl in Controls.OfType(Of CustomControl)
    If [criteria met]
        _CustomControl.CustomProperty = value
    End If
Next
```

If you don't want to use that, than you need to cast to the `CustomControl` type before attempting to access `CustomProperty` like so:

```
For Each _CustomControl As Control In Controls
    If TypeOf _CustomControl Is CustomControl And [criteria met]
        DirectCast(_CustomControl,CustomControl).CustomProperty = value
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [`AndAlso`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/andalso-operator) on your condition:

```
For Each _CustomControl As Control In Controls
    If TypeOf _CustomControl Is CustomControl AndAlso [criteria met]
        _CustomControl.CustomProperty = value
    End If
Next
```

You try to access the `CustomProperty` on the default `Control`. With `AndAlso` the second part of the condition is not evaluated if the first part isn't true.

[You can find some explanations about the difference between `And` and `AndAlso` on StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302047/what-is-the-difference-between-and-and-andalso-in-vb-net)